# In Oracle, can I do an "insert or update values into TABLE"

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00001

I have a table with two number columns, and a unique constraint over them both. I would like to insert a new pair of values UNLESS the pair already exists. What is the simplest way to do this?

If I do

```
insert into TABLE values (100,200)
```

and the pair already exists I get a ORA-00001 error, so I would like to do something like

```
insert or update into TABLE values (100,200)
```

Comment: if the pair of values already exists, what are you trying to update?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle: how to UPSERT (update or insert into a table?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237327/oracle-how-to-upsert-update-or-insert-into-a-table)

Comment: @Nellius: Nothing, really. But if they _don't_ exist I would like to insert them. The values come from an external source. I would like to insert them into the database, but I don't want to write extra code that first checks whether they are already present.

Comment: @Tony Andrews: Yes, and in addition your answer there (merging the "old fashioned way") worked very well for me. Thanks. Should I close this as duplicate, or would you like to re-enter your answer for the reputation? :-)

Comment: I don't think that would be cricket!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [MERGE](http://psoug.org/reference/merge.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
insert into table
select :a, :b from dual
where not exists (select 1 from table where column1 = :a and column2=:b)
```