# How do I INSERT or UPDATE in SQL Server tables via Python?

Tags: python, sql-server, dataframe, pyodbc

I'm trying to save  records in an SQL Server database via Python and KEY is a primary key. Below is my Python code: -

```
import pyodbc
cnxn_str = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+db+';UID='+user+';PWD='+password_db)
cursor = cnxn_str.cursor()   

for index, row in dataframe.iterrows():
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Table(USER,SENDER,RECEIVER,DAY,ORIGIN,KEY) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)",
           row.USER,row.SENDER,row.RECEIVER,row.DAY,row.ORIGIN,row.KEY)
cnxn_str.commit()
cursor.close()
```

The SQL in the code saves dataframe  rows in the database table. However, I'm interested in modifying the above code to save records  as per these conditions. In case row.KEY matches any record in the table, it should  update it with current dataframe values. If there is  no match, then an insertion should suffice. How  can I modify this code to match meet this requirement?

Comment: SQL has a [`MERGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) statement.

Comment: Although `MERGE` is the common suggestion, there's downsides to it in many situations. Your question is basically this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21208719/update-if-exists-else-insert-in-sql-server-2008