# SQL Server how to UPDATE if exists else INSERT by Python

Tags: python, sql-server

I've searched many articles in stack overflow but not able to find one meeting my requirement. Below is what I'm referring to.

[UPDATE if exists else INSERT in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21208719/update-if-exists-else-insert-in-sql-server-2008)

**My requirement**
Using Python to create an ETL procedure: extract data from a source, transform to a dataframe then upload to MS SQL Server. If a duplicate row with same product_id is found, then UPDATE SQL database otherwise INSERT a new row.

**My Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

# Import CSV
data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\...\product.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
records = df.values.tolist()

# Connect to SQL Server
server = 'AAABBBCCC\SQLEXPRESS' 
database = 'abcdefg' 
username = 'User' 
password = '' 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';Trusted_Connection=True;')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

#Insert Data
sql_insert = '''
    UPDATE [atetestdb].[dbo].[products] 
    SET product_name = ?
    ,price = ?
    WHERE product_id = ?

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        INSERT INTO [atetestdb].[dbo].[products] 
            (product_id, product_name, price)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?)
'''

cursor.executemany(sql_insert, records)

cnxn.commit()
```

**My Result**
The error message I got:

> The SQL contains 6 parameter markers, but 3 parameters were supplied

It seems something wrong with the SQL comment. Could someone help? Any other solution to meet my requirement is also appreciated.

**My Dataset in SQL database**

| product_id | product_name | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Desk | 1900 |
| 2 | Printer | 200 |
| 3 | Tablet | 350 |
| 4 | Keyboard | 80 |
| 5 | Monitor | 1200 |
| 6 | Desk | 900 |

**My Dataset in csv file**

| product_id | product_name | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Monitor | 600 |

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I modified my table image to text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the batch to have local variables for each parameter, eg:

```
sql_insert = '''
    declare @product_id int = ?
    declare @product_name varchar(100) = ?
    declare @price decimal(10,2) = ?
        
    UPDATE [atetestdb].[dbo].[products] 
    SET product_name = @product_name, price = @price
    WHERE product_id = @product_id

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        INSERT INTO [atetestdb].[dbo].[products] 
            (product_id, product_name, price)
        VALUES (@product_id, @product_name, @price)
'''
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! I found the order of declare statement has to match my table. So, I have to swap the product_id to first row.

Answer (score 3):

You can go for simple MERGE statement.

```
MERGE [atetestdb].[dbo].[products] as t
USING (Values(?,?,?)) AS s(product_id, product_name, price)
ON t.product_id = s.product_id 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET 
         t.product_name = s.product_name
        ,t.price = s.price
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
     THEN INSERT (product_id, product_name, price)
          VALUES (s.product_id, s.product_name, s.price);
```

Comment: Thanks! But it pops out the error message "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Values'".

Comment: @KelvinLo, sorry. I have updated my answer. it should work

Comment: Thank you @Venkataraman R Your code also works! I corrected some variables and adjusted column order to make it work.

Comment: @KelvinLo, Glad it helped. you are welcome.