# UPDATE and EXISTS Clause

Tags: sql, oracle

Please help me identify what I am doing wrong in the query below :

**The following code gives an error: ORA-00904 : DPT.DEPTNO : invalid identifier**

```
UPDATE emp1 
SET ename = (SELECT dname
FROM dpt 
WHERE dpt.deptno = emp1.deptno)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ename
FROM emp1 
WHERE emp1.deptno = dpt.deptno);
```

the first half of the query works fine on its own :

```
UPDATE emp1 
SET ename = (SELECT dname
FROM dpt 
WHERE dpt.deptno = emp1.deptno)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the wrong table in the second subquery:

```
UPDATE emp1 
SET ename = (SELECT dname FROM dpt WHERE dpt.deptno = emp1.deptno)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dpt WHERE emp1.deptno = dpt.deptno);
----------------------------^
```

It is curious that you are setting a column called `ename` to the name of what is presumably a department.  But that is another matter.

Comment: I still don't understand why can't i use emp1?  <br>  and I am just  practicing my concepts so trying to turn things around without having to make new tables. </br>

Comment: @ManushreeMishra . . . You are using `emp1` in the outer query.  You want to compare it to `dpt`, based on the rest of the logic in the query.

Comment: This answer is more applicable - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015199/oracle-sql-update-if-exists-else-insert