# How to run SQL scripts and get data on application startup?

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, sql-scripts

I am developing a Spring Boot application. At the moment some of my configs are hard coded (e.g. Hystrix properties).

So I would like to get these configs on my application start up time or just after that.

Is it possible to do that using Spring Boot? I mean to run SQL script on start up and get data.

How should properties/configs be retrieved and stored in my application?

I am using MyBatis and Oracle DB.

Comment: Put them in application.yml. Make them profile dependent.

Comment: I had such idea, but at the moment I would like to get values from DB :)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

By default, Spring-Boot loads `data.sql` and/or `data-${platform}.sql`.

However, keep in mind that the script would be loaded at every start, so I would think it makes more sense (at least for production), to just have the values already present in the database, not re-inserted at every start. **I've personally only used database initialization for test/dev purposes when using a memory database.** Still, this is the feature provided by Spring-Boot.

source: [spring-boot-howto-database-initialization](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html):

> Spring JDBC has a DataSource initializer feature. Spring Boot enables
> it by default and loads SQL from the standard locations schema.sql and
> data.sql (in the root of the classpath). In addition Spring Boot will
> load the schema-${platform}.sql and data-${platform}.sql files (if
> present).

src/main/resources/**data-oracle.sql:**

```
insert into...
insert into...
```

- You may define the platform with: `spring.sql.init.platform=oracle`.
- You may change the name of the sql script to load with: `spring.sql.init.data-locations=myscript.sql`.
- Along with `data.sql`, Spring-boot also loads `schema.sql` (before `data.sql`).
- You could also have an "update or insert" logic in your data.sql: [oracle sql: update if exists else insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015199/oracle-sql-update-if-exists-else-insert)

Comment: I don't need to insert data. I need to get data from DB :)

Comment: take a look at how spring batch works ther is no need to run select command on startup.. can t see the purpose.. if you wanna load data on startup would better use a batch easy@Laurynas

Comment: Hello @alexbt

The title posted by that user is a bit misleading. 

He wishes to load the configurations from the database at Application launch (rather than creating and initializing Schema).

Comment: p.s. to load custom filenames, you can set `spring.datasource.schema`

Comment: Configuration property 'spring.datasource.platform' and 'spring.datasource.data' have been Deprecated. Instead use spring.sql.init.platform=h2
spring.sql.init.data-locations=classpath:/data.sql

Comment: Spring docs link seems to be not working anymore probably because doc is updated since then. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization.using-basic-sql-scripts is the new link

Answer (score 14):

What worked for me is using `DataSourceInitializer`:

```
@Bean
public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer(@Qualifier("dataSource") final DataSource dataSource) {
    ResourceDatabasePopulator resourceDatabasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
    resourceDatabasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("/data.sql"));
    DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
    dataSourceInitializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
    dataSourceInitializer.setDatabasePopulator(resourceDatabasePopulator);
    return dataSourceInitializer;
}
```

> Used to set up a database during initialization and clean up a
>   database during destruction.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/init/DataSourceInitializer.html

Comment: The tittle posted by that user is a bit misleading. He wishes to load the configurations from database at Application launch (rather than creating and initializing Schema).

Comment: @PhilipDilip this solution can be use to execute a script, it's not only for initializing a schema.

Answer (score 10):

If want to load data from sql script after startup, use ResourceDatabasePopulator class object as follows.

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Component
public class InitializeData {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void loadData() {
            ResourceDatabasePopulator resourceDatabasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator(false, false, "UTF-8", new ClassPathResource("data.sql"));
        resourceDatabasePopulator.execute(dataSource);
    }
}
```

It will easily load data from sql file and dont worry about wrong sql statements inside sql file as it will be ignored.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to insert data based on some business logic I would recommend you to have Event Listener. So basically on application startup "OnApplicationEvent" as it is annotated with @EventListener method will be called automatically.

Also as in your case you need to get the data, you simply use your repository object to get the data as well.

Here's one example:

```
@Component
public class OnApplicationStartUp {

   @Autowired
   private ServiceRepository repository;


   @EventListener
   public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {

       //Write your business logic here.
       if (repository.findAll().size() <= 0) {
           preloadData();
       }else{
           fetchData();
       }
   }

    private void preloadData() {

       List<Service> services = new ArrayList<>();
       Service someService= new Service("name", "type");
       services.add(someService);
       ...
       ...
       repository.saveAll(services);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you getting from application.properties file you can use Environment class.
Like that

```
Autowired
private Environment environment;
...
environment.getProperty("propertyName")
```

or you can define your own property file. then you can get from it with 
`@PropertySource(name = "myProperties", value = "example.properties")` annotation

You need to use @Value annotation to get a specific value from the property file which you defined.

```
@Value("${propertyNameInYourPropertFile}")
private String url;
```

And You want to start something when Application is just started, you can use this before a method

```
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
```

But need to use @Service or @Component Annotation, which Class has the method.

Totally, You can use this.

example.properties :

```
url=yourValue
userName=yourDBUserName
password=yourDBPassword
```

example class :

```
@Service
@PropertySource(name = "myProperties", value = "example.properties")
public class Start{

    @Value("${url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${userName}")
    private String userName;

    @Value("${password}")
    private String password;


    //Run this method when application started
    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public ResultSet getConnection()
    {

        //Connect to Database
        Connection connection = null;
        String QUERY="your sql query";
        try {
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password );
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }


        //Run your query
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            stmt = connection.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(QUERY);
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        return rs;
    }

}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on edit and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Define a Spring Bean (e.g. GlobalConfigurationBean)
   with Scope: @Scope(scopeName = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_APPLICATION) 
   This Bean would be responsible for fetching the data from your Database Table (maintaining Configuration properties) during Bean initialization.
2. Annotate a method using @PostConstruct.
    This method would have the logic to fetch the Configuration parameters from your database table.
3. The scope of this bean would ensure that required Configurations are fetched only once from the database table (e.g. using Hibernate query or pure native SQL) and 
    are available to all beans from different contexts within same application.

Now just inject this bean wherever you wish to use those Configuration Properties or parameters.

OR 

Use:: Apache Commons DatabaseConfiguration <-- 
NOTE:: It doesn't support caching. But I guess you don't need caching as the database configuration properties should be loaded only once, at the start of application launch. 

OR 

Trandational Old way: Define a Custom Implementation of "PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer" by extending it, and define it as a Spring Bean.
This implementaion should have logic to fetch the data from your database table, that holds configuration properties.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize Database(Execute schema.sql and data.sql) using JDBC in spring boot

Note: Follow these steps

1. create sample project pom.xml (edit it based on your version)

   ```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
                <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
                <parent>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.1</version>
                    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
                </parent>
                <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                <artifactId>Init_Sql_Script</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <name>Init_Sql_Script</name>
                <description>Initialize a Database Using Basic SQL Scripts</description>
                <properties>
                    <java.version>17</java.version>
                </properties>
                <dependencies>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <build>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </build>

            </project>
   ```
2. application properties && create new db name like employee in ur DB

   ```
           # connection code for spring boot to your DB
           spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
           spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee
           spring.datasource.username=Hari
           spring.datasource.password=1998

           spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

           #--- control the sql db initialization (from schema.sql and data.sql)---
           spring. SQL.init.mode=always


           #---if any error it skips the script and executes the next script----
           #spring.sql.init.continue-on-error=true
   ```
3. create two SQL files (schema.sql-create table query and data.sql-insert query) in the resource folder
4. run the application after that check db thats all Try it.

It is working for me I Hope its working for u also