# many to many crud

Tags: sql, plsql, crud

I'm currently implementing CRUD for a project. I have a lot of `many-to-many` relationships. Some of them are table1_id, table2_id, and some of them have additional columns (price, amount, etc).

What is the best way to update `many-to-many` table: as you can see, there can be some information already along with new data.

`Example`

```
t1_id t2_id amount
1     3     15
2     4     50
```

I'd like to update this info and send some data like : `{1,3,15}`, `{2,5, 25}`. So i need to update the first line and insert a new line.
I want to create a function (pl/sql) that will take table of records and check whether it's a new record or record for update.

`Question`: Are there any better ways to implement this? Are there any patterns to accomplish that goal?

Answer (score 2):

The pattern you're looking for is usually called an "UPSERT": insert a row if one doesn't exist, otherwise update the existing row.  You'll still need to loop through your rows, but you can execute a single statement for each row.

I'm not sure about pl/sql but this question might help: [Oracle: how to UPSERT (update or insert into a table?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237327/oracle-how-to-upsert-update-or-insert-into-a-table)

Comment: Oracle directly supports upsert with the MERGE statement.  You will have to make a `select :v1, :v2, :v3 from dual` as the row you're merging into the table.

Answer (score 0):

I almost always do this lazily and just delete all the associated rows from the cross-reference table, then run an insert statement to link it back up.  This would ideally all be done within a transaction.  I haven't done much in terms of analyzing the performance, but it probably isn't too bad to do it that way, especially if you have a large number of updates to make.

Comment: I've done it once but I think it's not good for performance reasons. I'll have number of additional inserts, that's slower than select queries over indexed columns. Is't it?

Comment: This usually isn't a problem unless you have expensive check constraints.   That's not to say it's the best way.