# Update or Insert based on the value of a column in the table

Tags: sql, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Oracle: how to UPSERT (update or insert into a table?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237327/oracle-how-to-upsert-update-or-insert-into-a-table)

Could you guys give me an suggestion on how to proceed in the below situation:

```
Read table 2 column 1 
if value says the record exists in table 1
update table 1 record with table 2 record details
else(value says the record does not exist in table 1)
insert table 1 record with table 2 record details
```

I am beginner to Oracle SQL, Please let me know if there is a better approach..I was thinking about using cursors to solve this..

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Why can't you check against table 1?

Answer (score 6):

The simplest answer is to use the [`merge`](http://psoug.org/reference/merge.html) statement:

```
MERGE INTO table1 a
USING ( select column1, column2 
          from table2 ) b
ON ( a.column1 = b.column1 )
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  update set a.column2 = b.column2
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
  insert (a.column1, a.column2)
  values (b.column1, b.column2)
```

Simply put this takes everything from the `select` on `table2`. It then joins this query to `table1` on the condition. If there is a "match" then it updates, otherwise inserts.

The [documentation has more information](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) about various additional options that you don't, currently, require.

Comment: Thanks Ben, it almost served the purpose..first time it ran successfully but if i am running again it is throwing the error `unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables` any work around for this..tried with Distinct as mentioned in one of the other threads but it did not work.

Comment: Beware - there were numerous bugs concerning this feature in oracle9. We were even forbidden to use it until upgrade to oracle10.

Comment: @javanoob, it sounds like you don't have a unique set of rows after the first time you run it, i.e. you don't have a unique constraint / index on the table. Are the columns you're joining on unique _after_ you've run it once?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the merge statement.

http://psoug.org/reference/merge.html