# Oracle Merge. How can I use it?

Tags: oracle, plsql, upsert

I have this function:

```
      Procedure UpdateDefaultWeight  ( vYear Number, costWeight Number, qualityWeight Number, serviceWeight Number ) 
      AS

        type weight_table is table of Number(5,2) index by varchar2(50);
        weightArray weight_table;
        currentPosition varchar2(50);
      Begin

        weightArray('Cost Weighting')    := costWeight;
        weightArray('Quality Weighting') := qualityWeight;
        weightArray('Service Weighting') := serviceWeight;

        currentPosition := weightArray.first;

        Loop
          Exit When currentPosition is null;
          Insert Into GVS.GVSSD16_DFLT_WEIGHT
            ( cal_year, metric_name, metric_val )
          Values
            ( vYear, currentPosition, weightArray(currentPosition) ); 

          currentPosition := weightArray.next(currentPosition);
        End Loop;
      END;
```

Right now as I wrote it, it just does an INSERT.  However, I need it to UPSERT.  I've looked around at documentation on MERGE, but mainly it's just left me confused on how to apply the syntax to my specific case.

I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237327/oracle-how-to-upsert-update-or-insert-into-a-table) and [here](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Oracle/DBA_tips/SQL/SQL_14.shtml) and I get the jist of it, but syntax fails me.

Anyone care to help an Oracle newbie out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that cal_year and metric_name define the join criteria, this should get you close (untested):

```
MERGE INTO GVS.GVSSD16_DFLT_WEIGHT d
     USING (SELECT vYear AS YY,
                   currentPosition AS POS,
                   weightArray (currentPosition) AS WA
              FROM DUAL) v
        ON (d.cal_year = v.YY AND d.metric_name = v.pos)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
   UPDATE SET metric_val = v.WA
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN
   INSERT     (cal_year, metric_name, metric_val)
       VALUES (v.YY, v.POS, v.WA);
```

Comment: Damn near perfect.  Just needed parenthesis around the ON condition.

Thanks for the help.