# PL/SQL; Execute Function/Procedure Based On Condition

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I would like to execute an INSERT procedure condition to subject tuple not present within database.

I am not certain how to formulate the following

```
IF !(SELECT a1, a2, a3, FROM table) THEN
    INSERT VALUES INTO TABLE (a1, a2, a3)
ELSE
    -- Do Nothing
END IF
```

Would I need to utilize a cursor, grab the tuple, and then check each value against the attributes of the procedure?  I thought of that but would prefer not to if unnecessary.

Comment: You could use a MERGE statement: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606

Comment: Would [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570527/oracle-merge-how-can-i-use-it) pose as a suitable example use of MERGE for what I need?

Comment: Yes, except that you would need a "no-op" for the WHEN MATCHED case.  I thought "when matched then null" was allowed but apparently not, it would have to be something like "when matched then t.a1 = t.a1".  I think I have realised what you really need and will post an answer.

Comment: @TonyAndrews - just leave the `WHEN MATCHED` clause out if you don't want to use it - it's optional.

Comment: @Tony Provide an answer and I will nominate it.

Comment: @BobJarvis, thanks - I'm afraid I don't use MERGE as often as I should and am never 100% sure of the syntax!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
insert into table (col1, col2, col3)
select 'a1', 'a2', 'a3' from dual
where not exists
   (select null from table where col1='a1' and col2='a2' and col3='a3');
```