# PL/SQL Oracle ORA-24344

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad

I am receiving the following when creating a PL/SQL FUNCTION

```
Warning: compiled but with compilation errors
No errors.
```

When I view the Messages in TOAD, I see the following

```
[Warning] ORA-24344: success with compilation error
17/43   PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "PAGE_DCPN": invalid identifier
2/48    PLS-00201: identifier 'B2BOWNER.SSC_PAGE_MAP' must be declared
16/5    PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
(2: 0): Warning: compiled but with compilation errors
```

I am using the following PL/SQL command to create the table

```
DECLARE

v_create LONG;

v_drop LONG;

TABLE_DOES_NOT_EXIST exception;  
PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(TABLE_DOES_NOT_EXIST, -942); -- ORA-00942

TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(30) := 'B2BOWNER.SSC_Page_Map'; 

BEGIN

   BEGIN

       v_drop := 'DROP TABLE ' || TABLE_NAME; 

       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_drop;  

       EXCEPTION 

           WHEN TABLE_DOES_NOT_EXIST THEN NULL;

   END;

   v_create := 'CREATE TABLE ' ||  TABLE_NAME || ' (
                PAGE_ID_NBR   NUMERIC(10)   NOT NULL Check(Page_ID_NBR > 0),
                PAGE_TYPE     VARCHAR2(50)  NOT NULL, 
                PAGE_DCPN     VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY(Page_ID_NBR, Page_Type))';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_create; 

   COMMIT WORK;

   COMMIT COMMENT 'Create Table'; 

   EXCEPTION

      WHEN OTHERS THEN

        IF SQLCODE = -955 THEN

            NULL; -- suppresses ORA-00955 exception
        ELSE

            RAISE;
        END IF;

END;
```

The PL/SQL function I am trying to create is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION B2BOWNER.F_SSC_Page_Map_Insert(
                            p_page_id   IN B2BOWNER.SSC_Page_Map.PAGE_ID_NBR%TYPE, 
                            p_page_type IN B2BOWNER.SSC_Page_Map.PAGE_TYPE%TYPE, 
                            p_page_dcpn IN B2BOWNER.SSC_Page_Map.PAGE_DCPN%TYPE)

      RETURN INTEGER

IS

TABLE_DOES_NOT_EXIST exception;  
PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(TABLE_DOES_NOT_EXIST, -942); -- ORA-00942

BEGIN


MERGE INTO B2BOWNER.SSC_PAGE_MAP
USING (SELECT PAGE_ID_NBR ,PAGE_TYPE ,PAGE_DCPN FROM dual) 
ON (PAGE_ID_NBR = p_page_id AND PAGE_TYPE = p_page_type AND PAGE_DCPN = p_page_dcpn)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET PAGE_ID_NBR = p_page_id, PAGE_TYPE = p_page_type, PAGE_DCPN = p_page_dcpn
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (PAGR_ID_NBR, PAGE_TYPE, PAGE_DCPN) 
    VALUES(p_page_id, p_page_type, p_page_dcpn);


RETURN 0;

EXCEPTION

    WHEN TABLE_DOES_NOT_EXIST THEN

        RETURN -1;

    WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN

        RETURN -2;

    WHEN INVALID_NUMBER THEN

        RETURN -3;

    WHEN OTHERS THEN

        RETURN -4;

END F_SSC_Page_Map_Insert;

SHOW ERRORS PROCEDURE B2BOWNER.F_SSC_Page_Map_Insert;

GRANT EXECUTE ON F_SSC_Page_Map_Insert TO B2B_USER_DBROLE;
```

The PL/SQL create script executes to success with the usual

```
 PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

and is verified in toad under the schema `B2BOWNER.SSC_PAGE_MAP` as existing and all looks good.

I am new to using the `MERGE` procedure as evident 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23811731/pl-sql-execute-function-procedure-based-on-condition?noredirect=1#comment36633458_23811731) so that is likely where my problem is although it is not evident what part of the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot catch an ORA-00942 error in your `F_SSC_Page_Map_Insert` function, at least not as it is written.  If the table doesn't exist when the function is created, the function will fail to compile because the static reference to the table won't exist at the time the function is created.  You cannot catch compilation errors in a PL/SQL block, only runtime errors.

You could, I suppose, modify the function to use exclusively dynamic SQL to refer to the table.  That would cause the compiler to delay resolving the object references to runtime rather than at compilation which would allow you to catch the exception in your function.  That would also allow the function to compile successfully when the table didn't exist.  Of course, that would also make your function more complex, harder to write, harder to read, and harder to debug.  It would also almost certainly impose some performance penalties.

Is there a reason that you need the procedure to be created before the table exists?  Normally, that is complexity that you don't really need.  As such, you should avoid the complexity rather than adding code to try to handle it.

Comment: Is that why I am experiencing the ORA-24344?

Comment: @Mushy - It would appear to be, yes.

Comment: So then I should remark the lines of code out until the function is made then?  Would you suggest that?

Comment: @Mushy - Remove the `TABLE_DOES_NOT_EXIST` exception and that part of the exception handler from your function.  The function can never raise an error that the table doesn't exist at runtime.  Then ensure that the table exists before you try to create the function if you want the function to compile successfully.  Alternately, you can allow the function to be created with errors, then create the table, then recompile the function but that's generally more effort.