# Oracle SQL Developer: If Exists Update Else Insert Missing Right Parenthesis Compiler Error

Tags: sql, oracle, compiler-errors, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have been attempting to write a SQL Query in Oracle's SQL Developer that will update a row if it exists and insert one if it doesn't.  Besides the primary key(UNITOFMEASURE_USERID), there are three columns: UNITOFMEASUREID, USERID, and ACTIVE.  There is a unique constraint on combinations of UNITOFMEASUREID and USERID, so for each combination of values there is either one row or 0.
I have been trying two different SQL arrangements, and both of them return a similar compilation error complaining about a missing right parenthesis.
This is what I have tried:
First arrangement:

```
UPDATE NORSEMEN.UNITOFMEASURE_USER SET (ACTIVE=1) WHERE UNITOFMEASUREID=:unitOfMeasureId AND USERID=:userId
IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
    INSERT INTO NORSEMEN.UNITOFMEASURE_USER (UNITOFMEASUREID, USERID) VALUES (:unitOfMeasureId, :userId)
```

SQL Developer error response for first arrangement:

```
Error at Command Line:1 Column:46
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Second arrangement:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM NORSEMEN.UNITOFMEASURE_USER WHERE UNITOFMEASUREID=:unitOfMeasureId AND USERID=:userId)
    UPDATE NORSEMEN.UNITOFMEASURE_USER SET (ACTIVE = 1) UNITOFMEASUREID=:unitOfMeasureId AND USERID=:userId
ELSE
    INSERT INTO NORSEMEN.UNITOFMEASURE_USER (UNITOFMEASUREID, USERID) VALUES (:unitOfMeasureId, :userId)
```

SQL Developer error response for second arrangement:

```
Error at Command Line:2 Column:47
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I have not been able to figure out why SQL Developer thinks there is a missing parenthesis.
Can anyone help?

Comment: As well as Joachim's observation, `@@rowcount` is not Oracle syntax. Presumably you're doing this in a PL/SQL block, given the second error is against line 2. Either way, you might want to consider the [`merge` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/statements_9016.htm) to do an 'upsert'. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/237327/266304) for example.

Comment: All your procedural code looks like Microsofts SQL Server's T-SQL, not Oracle's PL/SQL. For example in PL/SQL an `if` statement with no `else` is `IF condition THEN <<one or more statements>> END IF;` With an else `IF condition THEN <<one or more statements>> ELSE <<one or more statements>> END IF;` I recommend you look for a different reference materials, tutorials, and/or examples to learn PL/SQL from. Free reference: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/toc.htm. Not free tutorial: http://www.amazon.com/dp/0596514468

Comment: And Oracle's PL/SQL does not allow subqueries in conditionals of `if` statements. So second would be `SELECT count(*) INTO :rowCount FROM NORSEMEN.UNITOFMEASURE_USER WHERE UNITOFMEASUREID=:unitOfMeasureId AND USERID=:userId and ROWNUM <= 1; IF :rowCount > 0 THEN ... ELSE ... END IF;` Just use `merge`.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.  They have been instructive, and I understand better now why my SQL query was not compiling.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case there is a little need of using any procedural processing to update `active` column of the table if records matching condition is true, or insert new record if it's not. You can do it in a single statement using [merge](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/statements_9016.htm).

```
merge 
 into unitofmeasure_user
using dual
  on (
      unitofmeasureid = :unitOfMeasureId AND 
      userid = :userId
     )
when matched 
then update 
        set active = 1
when not matched
then insert (unitofmeasureid, userid) 
       values (:unitOfMeasureId, :userId);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks Nocholas!  I've tried your solution, and it does exactly what I wanted it to do.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error that will give you that exact error message;

```
UPDATE NORSEMEN.UNITOFMEASURE_USER SET (ACTIVE=1) WHERE ...
```

should be

```
UPDATE NORSEMEN.UNITOFMEASURE_USER SET ACTIVE=1 WHERE ...
```

In the second arrangement, you're also missing a `WHERE`.

Comment: Thanks Joachim.  I didn't realize that I shouldn't use parentheses there.