# Oracle alternative for MySQL REPLACE INTO

Tags: mysql, oracle

In MySQL we use

```
REPLACE INTO
```

to insert if a row doesn't exist and to update if it exists.

Is there a corresponding command in Oracle?

Comment: Don't use `REPLACE INTO` in MySQL, rather use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237327/oracle-how-to-upsert-update-or-insert-into-a-table/2692441#2692441

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
MERGE
INTO    destTable d
USING   (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    sourceTable
        ) s
ON      (s.id = d.id)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT  (id, destCol1, destCol2)
VALUES  (id, sourceCol1, sourceCol2)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET     destCol1 = sourceCol1,
        destCol2 = sourceCol2
```

Comment: Do I actually need another table to merge from? Or is there a way to include the data in the command?

Comment: To answer my own question, I guess it can be done using `dual`: http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Oracle/DBA_tips/SQL/SQL_5.shtml

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like `Merge` in Oracle

Use

```
 Merge Into myTable s
   USING Select x from y;
```

[See the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9016.htm)