# How to use Repeated Placeholder Names in anonymous PL/SQL block?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to run an [UPSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2692441/27862) on a table `Person` like this:

```sql
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[
        MERGE INTO Person p
        USING (SELECT :x id, :y first_name, :z last_name FROM Dual) data

        ON (p.id = :x) -- note the repeated placeholder :x here

        WHEN MATCHED THEN
              UPDATE SET p.first_name = data.first_name, p.last_name = data.last_name
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
              INSERT (id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (data.id, data.first_name, data.last_name)
    ]' USING 123, 'Foo', 'Bar';
END;
/
```

If I run the code as given above, Oracle throws a `ORA-01008: not all variables bound ORA-06512: at line 2`

According to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS633) this is not supposed to happen at this point (inside an anonymous block). What am I doing wrong?

<sub>I know that I can work around this if I supply four arguments `… USING 123, 'Foo', 'Bar', 123;` and this works just fine, but obviously I don't want to repeat myself. Edit: as pointed out in the answers, `ON (p.id = data.id)` is another possible workaround.</sub>

The question is not how to work around this, it's more about understanding the cause of this error in this situation.

Comment: Your comment refers to `placeholder :1`; are you actually using positional or named bind variables? (And how contrived is this example - why aren't you doing `ON (p.id = data.id)`?)

Comment: @AlexPoole I fixed the comment. I tried both `:1,:2,:3` and `:x,:y,:z`, both yield the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be misinterpreting the documentation:

> If the dynamic SQL statement represents an anonymous PL/SQL block or a
>   CALL statement, repetition of placeholder names is significant.

This states that if the statement *that is being dynamically executed* is a PL/SQL block, then the bind variable don't have to be repeated. Your dynamic statement is a SQL statement, which does not qualify. You can fix this by adding `begin` and `end;` to the dynamic statement:

```
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[
        BEGIN
           MERGE INTO Person p
           USING (SELECT :x id, :y first_name, :z last_name FROM Dual) data    
           ON (p.id = :x) -- note the repeated placeholder :x here    
           WHEN MATCHED THEN
              UPDATE SET p.first_name = data.first_name, p.last_name = data.last_name
           WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
              INSERT (id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (data.id, data.first_name, data.last_name)
        END;
    ]' USING 123, 'Foo', 'Bar';
END;
/
```

---

In an case, it's simple to fix this statement without repeating the bind variable:

```
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[
        MERGE INTO Person p
        USING (SELECT :x id, :y first_name, :z last_name FROM Dual) data
        ON (p.id = data.id) 
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
              UPDATE SET p.first_name = data.first_name, p.last_name = data.last_name
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
              INSERT (id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (data.id, data.first_name, data.last_name)
    ]' USING 123, 'Foo', 'Bar';
END;
/
```

---

Finally, I feel I must point out that there's little reason to use dynamic SQL in this situation. Unless there's more going on that is affecting the SQL being run, this should just be a static SQL statement.

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation you linked to](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS632) says that the problem is; or at least the previous section does:

> If the dynamic SQL statement does not represent an anonymous PL/SQL block or a CALL statement, repetition of placeholder names is insignificant. Placeholders are associated with bind variables in the USING clause by position, not by name.

You [referred to the part](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS633) that said:

> If the dynamic SQL statement represents an anonymous PL/SQL block or a CALL statement, repetition of placeholder names is significant. Each unique placeholder name must have a corresponding bind variable in the USING clause. If you repeat a placeholder name, you need not repeat its corresponding bind variable. All references to that placeholder name correspond to one bind variable in the USING clause.

Your dynamic SQL statementis *not* an anonymous block. You're executing your dynamic SQL *within* an anonymous block, but that's irrelevant; it's what the `execute immediate` is doing that matters. And that is a plain SQL `merge` statement.

So you have to repeat the values, you can't avoid that - unless you create a procedure that does the `merge` and pass the three bind variables as arguments to that, once each. Or create an anonymous block wrapper around your statement, which seems a bit pointless, but maybe illustrates the difference in behaviour; this will work:

```
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[
      BEGIN
        MERGE INTO Person p
        USING (SELECT :x id, :y first_name, :z last_name FROM Dual) data

        ON (p.id = :x) 

        WHEN MATCHED THEN
              UPDATE SET p.first_name = data.first_name, p.last_name = data.last_name
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
              INSERT (id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (data.id, data.first_name, data.last_name);
      END;
    ]' USING 123, 'Foo', 'Bar';
END;
/
```

Note the `BEGIN`/`END` inside the dynamic statement.

Or in this case, as noted in comments and another answer, change your code to do `ON (p.id = data.id)` - which is just avoiding the issue...

Comment: A simpler alternative to creating a procedure would be to add `begin` and `end` to the dynamic SQL, which would make it an anonymous block.

Comment: @Allan - yes, I just added that option *8-) Ugh, sorry, I hadn't seen your answer for some reason... at least since it was edited.