# Updating a SQL table

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am doing a Java program in which I am reading input from some files and if it contains any string that I have in my list I have to update the table with name and its count.
First i created a table as follows

```
 create table mobile(name varchar2(20),count int,primary key(name));
```

for instance,if I read string like "Sony unviels its new phone", table must be updated with name as sony count as 1.

what my doubt is initially it is an empty table. Can we update it as I said.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Added `oracle` tag due to the usage of `varchar2`

Comment: Of course you can, change int to number for count column name. And count is a reserved key word in Oracle.

Comment: thanks @Polppan..but how to do that for sql..

Comment: @Reddevil You mean SQL statement?

Answer (score 1):

First table creation

```
CREATE TABLE mobile
(
   t_name    VARCHAR (20),
   t_count   NUMBER,
   PRIMARY KEY (t_name)
);
```

And insert statement

```
INSERT INTO mobile
     VALUES ('Sony', 1);
```

Single statement for insert and update

```
MERGE INTO mobile t
     USING (SELECT *
              FROM mobile
             WHERE LOWER (t_name) = 'sony') s
        ON (t.t_name = s.t_name)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
   UPDATE SET t.t_count = t_count+1
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN
   INSERT     (t_name, t_count)
       VALUES ('sony', 1);
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @Polppan...thankz...but i want an update stmt as when I have a string which again contains sony I have to update it so i want a single query to do all tis

Answer (score 0):

Either you prepopulate you table with your given word list so something like

```
CREATE TABLE mobile(
  name varchar2(20),
  count_column int,
  primary key(name)
);

INSERT INTO mobile (name, count_column) VALUES 
('Sony', 0);
```

or you are adding some magic to your Java code which is deciding whether to do an UPDATE or an INSERT.

As an simple would look like theoretical

```
 UPDATE mobile SET count_column to count_column+1 where name = 'Sony';
```

this will fail if there is none entry given.

Comment: @frlan...thankz for ur reply...what i am asking is can we do that update command when the table is empty..

Comment: The answer is: If you are not adding a procedure doing the decision insert/update for you, most likely not.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to execute an `UPSERT` like query , since oracle doesn't have it, you have to do a workaround  to resolve this. please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237327/oracle-how-to-upsert-update-or-insert-into-a-table) .