# stored procedure using the IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am researching issues regarding oracle. I'm creating stored procedures and boot the following errors I also show them in the picture, I hope to help me resolve the error.

[[image]]

Comment: what you need is a MERGE statement.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606).

Comment: It is wrongly closed. Question is about use of `IF Not Exists` not upsert.

Comment: @OP-Instead of using If not exists, use count * and see if it is 0.

Comment: In general it's more useful to copy/paste the query then link to a picture which is not like;y to be a helpful to others that might have the same problem in the future..

Comment: duplicate of [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/237327/146325)

Comment: @Utsav - I have re-opened this question but with hindsight I was wrong to do so and my original close vote was correct.  Unfortunately the OP has pasted a hard-to-read image of their code instead of posting their actual code.  But it appears they are testing for the existence of a specific key (`where id_datos=1`), and depending on the outcome updating the row or inserting a row *for that key*.  Which is the canonical use case for MERGE.

Answer (score 1):

You can add variable `v_count number :=0;` in your procedure to check if value exists.

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE_NAME(PARAMETERS) IS
V_COUNT NUMBER := 0;

BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(1)
INTO V_COUNT
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE .. .

IF V_COUNT = 0 THEN INSERT ... 
ELSIF UPDATE ... 
COMMIT;
END IF;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Merge is one way to do this. Another way is

```
INSERT INTO..
SELECT .... 
FROM DUAL 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM...)
```

I'm not going to try and transcribe your screenshot