# DAO: diffrence between InMemory implementation and Database Implementation

Tags: java, oracle, upsert

I'm confusing with implementation of **CRUD** methods for DAODatabase (for Oracle 11 xe).
The problem is that the **"U"**-method (update) in case of storing in generally to a Map collection inserts a new element or renews it (key-value data like `ID:AbstractBusinessObject`) in a Map collection. And you don't care about it, when you write something like `myHashMap.add(element)`. This method (update) is widely used in project's business logic.

Obviously, in case of using Oracle I must care about both inserting and renewing of existing elements. But I'm stucked to choose the way how to implement it:

There is no intrinsic function for so-called `UPSERT` in Oracle (at least in xe11g r2 version). However, I can emulate necessary function by SQL-query like this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id1, t1) 
  SELECT 11, 'x1' FROM DUAL 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id1 FROM mytble WHERE id1 = 11); 

UPDATE mytable SET t1 = 'x1' WHERE id1 = 11;
(src:http://stackoverflow.com/a/21310345/2938167)
```

*By using this kind of query (first - insert, second - update) I presume that the data mostly will be inserted not updated (at least it will be rather rare).* (May it be not optimal for concurrency?).

Ok, it is possible. But at this point I'm confusing to decide:

-- should I write an SQL function (with approriate arguments of course) for this and call it via Java

-- or should I simply handle a serie of queries for `preparedStatements` and do them via `.executeUpdate/.executeQuery`? Should I handle the whole `UPSERT` SQL code for one `preparedStatment` or split it into several SQL-queries and prepared statements inside one method's body? (I'm using Tomcat's pool of connections and I pass a connection instance via static method `getConnection()` to each method implementation in `DAODatabase`) ?

Is there another possibility to solve the `UPSERT` quest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent to your `UPSERT` statement would seem to be to use [`MERGE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm):

```
MERGE INTO mytable d
USING ( SELECT 11 AS id, 'x1' AS t1 FROM DUAL ) s
      ON ( d.id = s.id )
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT ( d.id, d.t1 ) VALUES ( s.id, s.t1 )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET d.t1 = s.t1;
```

You could also use (or wrap in a procedure):

```
DECLARE
  p_id MYTABLE.ID%TYPE := 11;
  p_t1 MYTABLE.T1%TYPE := 'x1';
BEGIN
  UPDATE mytable
  SET    t1 = p_t1
  WHERE  id = p_id;

  IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO mytable ( id, t1 ) VALUES ( p_id, p_t1 );
  END IF;
END;
/
```

However, when you are handling a CRUD request - if you are doing a Create action then it should be represented by an `INSERT` (and if something already exists then you ought to throw the equivalent of the HTTP status code `400 Bad Request` or `409 Conflict`, as appropriate) and if you are doing an Update action it should be represented by an `UPDATE` (and if nothing is there to update then return the equivalent error to `404 Not Found`.

So, while `MERGE` fits your description I don't think it is representative of a RESTful action as you ought to be separating the actions to their appropriate end-points rather than combining then into a joint action.