# How to insert or set field in Spring JPA?

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, oracle11g, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity in my service that I'd like to update asynchronously `@Async`.

For simplicity sake let it be the following entity:

```
public class Child {

 @Id
 private String name;

 private String bestFriend;

 private String worstFriend;

}
```

I have 2 places in my code where I need to asynchronously update a child's `bestFriend` and `worstFriend` properties, moreover, I'd like to make all calls to a repository are asynchronous. Notice, that each field is updated exactly once so the question is not in a race condition or versioning.

It means that on each update I have to check if a child with such name exists and if yes then set it's field to an updated value, if not then insert a new entity.

I thought that `REPEATABLE_READ` can assist me but Oracle 11g doesn't support this isolation level.

Could you give me your ideas or maybe a query that can execute "INSERT IF NOT EXISTS ELSE SET"?

Comment: Will this help?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2692441/2104638

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2692441), to perform an `UPSERT` in Oracle you need a `MERGE` clause.
You can write a native query or use Java with [FluentJPA](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA/wiki/UPSERT#oracle).