# How to resolve 'ORA-00933' with 'Insert...On Duplicate Key Update' SQL Query in Pandas?

Tags: sql, pandas, oracle, prepared-statement

I have an `Oracle Table` named `Consumer` with 10 columns where in `column# 2, 3 and 4` constitutes the primary key for it. Now, I want to insert into this table through a `Pandas Dataframe` using `Insert...On Duplicate Key Update` SQL statement.

First, I am converting any pandas NaNs or NaTs to Oracle None and then converting the Dataframe rows to tuples for insertion. If there is a primary key violation during insertion then I need to update only the last 4 columns in the table.

The code which I am using here is as follows:

```
df1 = df.astype(object).where(df.notnull(), None)
rows = [tuple(x) for x in df1.values]

query = """INSERT INTO CONSUMER VALUES (:1,:2,:3, :4, :5, :6, :7, :8, :9, :10) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
                                  DT = VALUES(:7),
                                  AT = VALUES(:8),
                                  OB = VALUES(:9),
                                  UT = VALUES(:10)"""

dbcur.executemany(query, rows)
dbcon.commit()
```

Where DT, AT, OB and UT are the names of the last 4 columns in the table.
But this is giving me the following error:

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Can someone please help me in finding out and correcting whats wrong with my code? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle: how to UPSERT (update or insert into a table?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237327/oracle-how-to-upsert-update-or-insert-into-a-table)

Comment: `@Mat` I am afraid ...but no. I need to do it using 'Insert..on Duplicate key' only. Could you please help me in rectifying the error?

Comment: Then switch to a database engine that supports that syntax.

Comment: `@Mat` I didnt understand your reply. Could you please elaborate? The DB I am using is Oracle12.2.

Answer (score 2):

The `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` syntax does not exist in Oracle (it is specific to MySQL). Oracle's equivalent is [the `MERGE` syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm), which for your use case would look like:

```
merge into consumer
using dual
on (col2 = :2 and col3 = :3 and col4 = :4)
when not matched then insert values (:1,:2,:3, :4, :5, :6, :7, :8, :9, :10)
when matched then update set dt = :7, at = :8, ob = :9, ut = :10
```

Note: you did not tell what the names of the primary key columns are, so I assumed `col2/3/4`. It would also be good to enumerate all columns for insert in the `not matched` clause of the query.

Comment: `@GMB` thanku for your reply but when I am excecuting this its giving me `cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01008: not all variables bound`. I just cant seem to understand what is the problem.

Comment: `@GMB` Also will this query work for the very first row insertion into the otherwise empty db table?

Comment: @Prachi: make sure that you do pass as many parameters as defined in the query (you need 10). Yes this works when the table is emplty (an insert occurs).