# Exasol UPSERT without using a second table?

Tags: database, rdbms, upsert, exasol

I could not find anything online about this problem. It seems ORACLE has a similar issue, which is handled using `DUAL`, as suggested in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2692441/1752676).

But how do we do the same in Exasol? According to [their documentation](https://docs.exasol.com/sql/merge.htm), you need to `MERGE` using a secondary table.

I tried to do the same approach as on Oracle, to no avail:

```
MERGE INTO TEST.TABLE USING SYS.DUAL ON "COLUMN_1" = "foo"
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET "COLUMN_2" = "quux"
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ("COLUMN_1", "COLUMN_2") VALUES ("foo", "bar")

[2021-12-15 11:22:47] [0A000] Feature not supported: Merge using a system table as source that is no view. (Session: 1719203050222845952)
```

Is it not possible to `UPSERT` like in other RDBMSs?

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the query like this:

```
MERGE INTO TEST.TABLE
USING (select 'foo' as s) s ON COLUMN_1 = s
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET COLUMN_2 = 'quux'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2) VALUES ('foo', 'bar')
```

This way you will eliminate DUAL table and keep correct join clause.