# Need to compare value in source table with standard values in spec table using MINUS concept of PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, minus

Team I have

Source table -->SRC_TBL as

```
TaxCode,ExemCode,CountryCode
TX1,EX1,US
TX1,EX2,UK
TX3,EX1,US
TX2,EX2,UK
```

3 Spec tables as --->
SPEC_TBL_TX

```
TaxCode
TX1
TX2
TX4
```

SPEC_TBL_EX

```
ExmCode
EX1
EX3
EX4
```

SPEC_TBL_CTY

```
Contry
US
IN
SG
```

Need to compare each source table values against values in each spec table values and update target table as follows

TAR_TBL

```
TaxCode,ExemCode,CountryCode,ERROR
TX1,EX1,US,VALID
TX1,EX2,UK,INVALID EX code+ Invalid Country
TX3,EX1,US,INVALID TX Code
TX2,EX2,UK,INVALID EX code+ Invalid Country
```

Need to implement with pl/sql MINUS concept. Will it require any BULK COLLECT logic too for bulk collections?

Comment: Can you explain how do you determine whether a tuple is valid, especially in view of your second record?

Comment: My second row of source has TX1,EX2,UK. where TX1 is valid value in 1st spec tbl. EX2 is not valid value against list of valid values in second spec table. UK is not valid value against valid list of values in 3rd spec table

Comment: I find 3 answers,thnx. All 3 answs give results only, but I need to insert the result to a column in target table. "TAR_TBL". Any special case i should add here?

Comment: I have edited my answer with details about insert-select and update-join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can left join your source table with the others and use case-when to determine when the pair was null, i.e., has no example in the corresponding target spec table:

```
select SRC_TBL.TaxCode, SRC_TBL.ExemCode, SRC_TBL.CountryCode, 
case 
    when SPEC_TBL_TX.TaxCode is null then 'error1'
    else ''
end ||
case
   when SPEC_TBL_EX.ExemCode is null then 
   case when SPEC_TBL_TX.TaxCode is null then '+'
        else ''
   end
   ||
   'error2'
   else ''
end ||
case 
    when SPEC_TBL_CTY.CountryCode is null then
    case when SPEC_TBL_TX.TaxCode is null or SPEC_TBL_EX.ExemCode is null then '+'
         else ''
    end
    ||
    ''
    else ''
end
as ERROR
from SRC_TBL
left join SPEC_TBL_TX
on SRC_TBL.TaxCode = SPEC_TBL_TX.TaxCode
left join SPEC_TBL_EX
on SRC_TBL.ExemCode = SPEC_TBL_EX.ExemCode
left join SPEC_TBL_CTY
on SRC_TBL.CountryCode = SPEC_TBL_CTY.CountryCode
```

If you need to insert this into a table, then you can insert-select, like

```
insert target_table(TaxCode, ExemCode, CountryCode, ERROR)
select ...
from ...
```

The ... above represent that whatever your query is, you can use it to specify what to insert into the target table. If you need to update, then you can update join, see https://oracle-base.com/articles/23c/direct-joins-for-update-and-delete-statements

So I recommend to update join first to update the error of whatever records that already exist and then do an insert-select, but in the insert-select make sure that you left join with the target table by the three identifier columns (TaxCode, ExemCode, CountryCode) you have matching the source table and check in the `where` clause that the target table's records are null, so you do not have a match yet in the target table, so you need to insert.

You could also do upserts, see [How to UPSERT (update or insert into a table?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237327/how-to-upsert-update-or-insert-into-a-table)

Comment: @BalaganeshMohanavel happy to help. Please let me know if you manage to solve the problem or if you stumble into some further issues. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't need PL/SQL at all. See the following example which in

- `temp1` outer joins source table to all other tables and returns the *keyword* if there's a mismatch
- `temp2` aggregates the result (which means that - if `NULL` - everything is OK; otherwise, something is *invalid*
- final query just displays it nicely

---

```
SQL> WITH
  2     temp
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT s.taxcode,
  5                s.exmcode,
  6                s.countrycode,
  7                CASE WHEN tx.taxcode IS NOT NULL THEN '' ELSE 'taxcode' END status
  8           FROM src_tbl s LEFT JOIN spec_tbl_tx tx ON tx.taxcode = s.taxcode
  9         UNION ALL
 10         SELECT s.taxcode,
 11                s.exmcode,
 12                s.countrycode,
 13                CASE WHEN ex.exmcode IS NOT NULL THEN '' ELSE 'exmcode' END status
 14           FROM src_tbl s LEFT JOIN spec_tbl_ex ex ON ex.exmcode = s.exmcode
 15         UNION ALL
 16         SELECT s.taxcode,
 17                s.exmcode,
 18                s.countrycode,
 19                CASE WHEN cy.countrycode IS NOT NULL THEN '' ELSE 'countrycode' END status
 20           FROM src_tbl s LEFT JOIN spec_tbl_cty cy ON cy.countrycode = s.countrycode),
 21     temp2
 22     AS
 23        (  SELECT taxcode,
 24                  exmcode,
 25                  countrycode,
 26                  LISTAGG (status, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NULL) status
 27             FROM temp
 28         GROUP BY taxcode, exmcode, countrycode)
 29  SELECT taxcode,
 30         exmcode,
 31         countrycode,
 32         CASE WHEN status IS NULL THEN 'VALID' ELSE 'INVALID: ' || status END result
 33    FROM temp2;
```

Result:

```
TAXCODE EXMCODE COUNTRYCODE     RESULT
------- ------- --------------- ------------------------------
TX1     EX1     US              VALID
TX1     EX2     UK              INVALID: countrycode, exmcode
TX2     EX2     UK              INVALID: countrycode, exmcode
TX3     EX1     US              INVALID: taxcode

SQL>
```

---

Note that you wouldn't have any problems (nor have to search for *invalid values* if there were foreign key constraints properly set, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE src_tbl_new
(
   taxcode       VARCHAR2 (3) REFERENCES spec_tbl_tx,
   exmcode       VARCHAR2 (3) REFERENCES spec_tbl_ex,
   countrycode   VARCHAR2 (2) REFERENCES spec_tbl_cty
);
```

Comment: Thanks Little for this..will execute and try learn this logic

Comment: I have query here..my source tabl will have 10000 records and spec tables may be having  max 20 records each. Will it take more time to execute. Since we have time restrictions in OIC flow when use DB adapter. Hence we try to achieve using any bulk collect and minus

Comment: *Bulk collect* reads *PL/SQL*, which will most probably be slower than pure SQL. Number of rows involved is *low* (10.000, plus up to 20 each of other 3 tables).

Comment: Thanks Little for throwing light on this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS` with a correlated sub-query to find when the value does not match the SPEC tables:

```sql
SELECT s.*,
       COALESCE(
         TRIM(
           TRAILING '+' FROM
           CASE
           WHEN NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                           FROM   spec_tbl_tx t
                           WHERE t.taxcode = s.taxcode)
           THEN 'Invalid taxcode+'
           END
           || CASE
           WHEN NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                           FROM   spec_tbl_ex e
                           WHERE  e.exmcode = s.exemcode)
           THEN 'Invalid exemcode+'
           END
           || CASE
           WHEN NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                           FROM   spec_tbl_cty c
                           WHERE  c.country = s.countrycode)
           THEN 'Invalid countrycode+'
           END
         ),
         'VALID'
       ) AS error
FROM   src_tbl s
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE SRC_TBL (TaxCode, ExemCode, CountryCode) AS
SELECT 'TX1','EX1','US' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'TX1','EX2','UK' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'TX3','EX1','US' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'TX2','EX2','UK' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE SPEC_TBL_TX(TaxCode) AS
SELECT 'TX1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'TX2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'TX4' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE SPEC_TBL_EX(ExmCode) AS
SELECT 'EX1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'EX3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'EX4' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE SPEC_TBL_CTY(Country) AS
SELECT 'US' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'IN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SG' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| TAXCODE | EXEMCODE | COUNTRYCODE | ERROR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TX1 | EX1 | US | VALID |
| TX1 | EX2 | UK | Invalid exemcode+Invalid countrycode |
| TX3 | EX1 | US | Invalid taxcode |
| TX2 | EX2 | UK | Invalid exemcode+Invalid countrycode |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1PNizdbM)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Left joins and Case expression:

```sql
WITH    --    S a m p l e    D a t a :
    src_tbl (TAX_CODE, EXM_CODE, CTY_CODE) AS
        ( Select 'TX1','EX1','US' From Dual Union All
          Select 'TX1','EX2','UK' From Dual Union All
          Select 'TX3','EX1','US' From Dual Union All
          Select 'TX2','EX2','UK' From Dual
        ), 
    spec_tbl_tx(TAX_CODE) AS
        ( Select 'TX1' From Dual Union All
          Select 'TX2' From Dual Union All
          Select 'TX4' From Dual
        ),
    spec_tbl_ex(EXM_CODE) AS
        ( Select 'EX1' From Dual Union All
          Select 'EX3' From Dual Union All
          Select 'EX4' From Dual
        ),
    spec_tbl_cty(CTY_CODE) AS
        ( Select 'US' From Dual Union All
          Select 'IN' From Dual Union All
          Select 'SG' From Dual
        )
```

```sql
--      S Q L :
Select  s.*,
        Case When tx.TAX_CODE Is Not Null And ex.EXM_CODE Is Not Null And cty.CTY_CODE Is Not Null Then 'VALID'
           When Coalesce(tx.TAX_CODE, ex.EXM_CODE, cty.CTY_CODE) Is Null Then 'INVALID: tax_code, exm_code, cty_code'
           When Coalesce(tx.TAX_CODE, ex.EXM_CODE) Is Null Then 'INVALID: tax_code, exm_code'
           When Coalesce(tx.TAX_CODE, cty.CTY_CODE) Is Null Then 'INVALID: tax_code, cty_code'
           When Coalesce(ex.EXM_CODE, cty.CTY_CODE) Is Null Then 'INVALID: exm_code, cty_code'
           When tx.TAX_CODE Is Null Then 'INVALID: tax_code'
           When ex.EXM_CODE Is Null Then 'INVALID: exm_code'
           When cty.CTY_CODE Is Null Then 'INVALID: cty_code'
        End "ERR_MSG"
From    src_tbl s
Left Join   spec_tbl_tx tx ON(tx.TAX_CODE = s.TAX_CODE)
Left Join   spec_tbl_ex ex ON(ex.EXM_CODE = s.EXM_CODE)
Left Join   spec_tbl_cty cty ON(cty.CTY_CODE = s.CTY_CODE)
Order By s.TAX_CODE
```

```sql
/*      R e s u l t :
TAX_CODE EXM_CODE CTY_CODE ERR_MSG                              
-------- -------- -------- -------------------------------------
TX1      EX1      US       VALID                                
TX1      EX2      UK       INVALID: exm_code, cty_code          
TX2      EX2      UK       INVALID: exm_code, cty_code          
TX3      EX1      US       INVALID: tax_code                     */
```

You asked for update of TAR_TBL and stated the expected final result with ERROR column populated so I suppose that there is a TAR_TBL with data like below:

```sql
/*
TAX_CODE EXM_CODE CTY_CODE ERROR                              
-------- -------- -------- -------------------------------------
TX1      EX1      US       Null                                
TX1      EX2      UK       Null        
TX2      EX2      UK       Null          
TX3      EX1      US       Null                                */
```

If that is the case then you could do the update of ERROR column in TAR_TBL with MERGE INTO TAR_TBL USING the above SQL:

```sql
Merge Into TAR_TBL t
USING ( Select  s.*,
                Case When tx.TAX_CODE Is Not Null And ex.EXM_CODE Is Not Null And cty.CTY_CODE Is Not Null Then 'VALID'
                   When Coalesce(tx.TAX_CODE, ex.EXM_CODE, cty.CTY_CODE) Is Null Then 'INVALID: tax_code, exm_code, cty_code'
                   When Coalesce(tx.TAX_CODE, ex.EXM_CODE) Is Null Then 'INVALID: tax_code, exm_code'
                   When Coalesce(tx.TAX_CODE, cty.CTY_CODE) Is Null Then 'INVALID: tax_code, cty_code'
                   When Coalesce(ex.EXM_CODE, cty.CTY_CODE) Is Null Then 'INVALID: exm_code, cty_code'
                   When tx.TAX_CODE Is Null Then 'INVALID: tax_code'
                   When ex.EXM_CODE Is Null Then 'INVALID: exm_code'
                   When cty.CTY_CODE Is Null Then 'INVALID: cty_code'
                End "ERR_MSG"
        From    src_tbl s
        Left Join   spec_tbl_tx tx ON(tx.TAX_CODE = s.TAX_CODE)
        Left Join   spec_tbl_ex ex ON(ex.EXM_CODE = s.EXM_CODE)
        Left Join   spec_tbl_cty cty ON(cty.CTY_CODE = s.CTY_CODE)
      ) x ON(x.TAX_CODE = t.TAX_CODE And x.EXM_CODE = t.EXM_CODE And x.CTX_CODE = t.CTY_CODE)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET t.ERROR = x.ERR_MSG
```

If TAR_TBL is empty and/or you need to insert rows then:

```sql
--  ... change just the WHEN clause like here
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (TAX_CODE, EXM_CODE, CTY_CODE, ERROR) VALUES(x.TAX_CODE, x.EXM_CODE, x.CTY_CODE, x.ERR_MSG)
```

And finaly if there is a case of something to update and something else to insert then

```sql
--  ...  change just the WHEN clause like here
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET t.ERROR = x.ERR_MSG
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (TAX_CODE, EXM_CODE, CTY_CODE, ERROR) VALUES(x.TAX_CODE, x.EXM_CODE, x.CTY_CODE, x.ERR_MSG)
```

Comment: Thanks DR, I hope it will not make any performance issue when used for 10000 records. I have 4 mins limitation to execute the query in OIC DB Adapter