# Need to Compare Values in SRC TBL with LOKKUP TBL and update ERROR Reason using PL/SQL Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle

Following my previous question ([Need to compare value in source table with standard values in spec table using MINUS concept of PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78027730/need-to-compare-value-in-source-table-with-standard-values-in-spec-table-using-m/78029576#78029576)), I missed an input parameter passing logic in my previous question.

My source table is

```
    Employee Table : EMP_TBL                    
                        
Batch_ID    Emp_ID  Account Src_Owner      Flag  Err_Reason
1           E1      SAL     FUSION           Y      VALID
1           E2      EXP     FUSION           Y      VALID
1           E5      SUS     ORCL             Y      VALID
2           E6      SUS     BBL              Y      VALID
2           E3      SAL     BBL              Y      VALID
2           E8      EXP     FUSION           Y      VALID
2           E4      SAL     EBS              Y      VALID
2           E11     SAL     EBS              Y      VALID 
1           E98     EXP     VBL              Y      VALID
1           E12     SUS     ORCL             Y      VALID
2           E43     DDD     VBL              Y      VALID
```

By default the FLAG = Y, Err_Reason=VALID

We have lookup table

```
LookupTable :   X_LOOKUP_TBL    
        
Prkey   Account Src_Owner
1       SAL     FUSION
2       EXP     EBS
3       null    ORCL
```

I need to compare my `EMP_TBL` columns `Account` and `Src_Owner` against the valid list of values for the same available in `X_LOOKUP_TBL`.
If the source column values don't match against look up values then need to update `Flag=N` and `Err_Reason=For which reason its failed like account or src_owner or both`; Hence my EMP_TBL will become as follows

```
Batch_ID    Emp_ID  Account Src_Owner   Flag    Err_Reason
1           E1      SAL     FUSION      Y       VALID
1           E2      EXP     FUSION      Y       VALID
1           E5      SUS     ORCL        N       InvalidAccount
2           E6      SUS     BBL         N       InvalidAccount, Invalid Owner
2           E3      SAL     BBL         N       Invalid Owner
2           E8      EXP     FUSION      Y       VALID
2           E4      SAL     EBS         Y       VALID
2           E11     SAL     EBS         Y       VALID
1           E98     EXP     VBL         N       Invalid Owner
1           E12     SUS     ORCL        N       InvalidAccount
2           E43     DDD     VBL         N       InvalidAccount, Invalid Owner
```

I will pl/sql procedure and will pass BATCH_ID as parameter and the SQL query should validation and update for that particular batch only.

In my loop I will call the procedure based on required batches only.

Batch 2 ==>E6 is failed and its Err_Reason=InvalidAccount, Invalid Owner  because it don't have valid account or src_owner that is available in look up table list of values.

Comment: Why is `E4` valid but `E11` invalid as they both have the combination `SAL/EBS`?

Comment: oh that's typo. Corrected

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `MERGE` statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO emp_tbl dst
USING (
  SELECT ROWID as rid,
         SUBSTR(
           CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1
                                 FROM   x_lookup_tbl x
                                 WHERE  x.account = e.account
                                 OR     (x.account IS NULL AND e.account IS NULL) )
           THEN ', InvalidAccount'
           END
           || CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1
                                    FROM   x_lookup_tbl x
                                    WHERE  x.src_owner = e.src_owner
                                    OR     (x.src_owner IS NULL AND e.src_owner IS NULL) )
           THEN ', InvalidOwner'
           END,
           3
         ) AS errors
  FROM   emp_tbl e
  -- WHERE  batch_id = :v_batch_id
) src
ON (src.rid = dst.ROWID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET flag       = CASE WHEN src.errors IS NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END,
      err_reason = COALESCE(src.errors, 'VALID');
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE EMP_TBL (Batch_ID, Emp_ID, Account, Src_Owner, Flag, Err_Reason) AS
SELECT 1, 'E1',  'SAL', 'FUSION', 'Y', CAST('VALID' AS VARCHAR2(30)) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'E2',  'EXP', 'FUSION', 'Y', 'VALID' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'E5',  'SUS', 'ORCL',   'Y', 'VALID' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'E6',  'SUS', 'BBL',    'Y', 'VALID' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'E3',  'SAL', 'BBL',    'Y', 'VALID' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'E8',  'EXP', 'FUSION', 'Y', 'VALID' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'E4',  'SAL', 'EBS',    'Y', 'VALID' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'E11', 'SAL', 'EBS',    'Y', 'VALID' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'E98', 'EXP', 'VBL',    'Y', 'VALID' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'E12', 'SUS', 'ORCL',   'Y', 'VALID' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'E43', 'DDD', 'VBL',    'Y', 'VALID' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE X_LOOKUP_TBL (Prkey, Account, Src_Owner) AS
SELECT 1, 'SAL', 'FUSION' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'EXP', 'EBS'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, null,  'ORCL'   FROM DUAL;
```

Then after the `MERGE`, the table contains:

| BATCH_ID | EMP_ID | ACCOUNT | SRC_OWNER | FLAG | ERR_REASON |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | E1 | SAL | FUSION | Y | VALID |
| 1 | E2 | EXP | FUSION | Y | VALID |
| 1 | E5 | SUS | ORCL | N | InvalidAccount |
| 2 | E6 | SUS | BBL | N | InvalidAccount, InvalidOwner |
| 2 | E3 | SAL | BBL | N | InvalidOwner |
| 2 | E8 | EXP | FUSION | Y | VALID |
| 2 | E4 | SAL | EBS | Y | VALID |
| 2 | E11 | SAL | EBS | Y | VALID |
| 1 | E98 | EXP | VBL | N | InvalidOwner |
| 1 | E12 | SUS | ORCL | N | InvalidAccount |
| 2 | E43 | DDD | VBL | N | InvalidAccount, InvalidOwner |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/K5OAJ04z)

Comment: Thanks MT0 for correcting my question and giving answer to the same.