# Add new row in a databound form with a Oracle Sequence as the primary key

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, ora-01400

I am connecting C# with Oracle 11g. I have a DataTable which i fill using an Oracle Data Adapter.

```
OracleDataAdapter da;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

da = new OracleDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Author", con);
da.Fill(dt);
```

I have few text boxes that I have databound to various rows in the data table.

```
txtAuthorID.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "AUTHORID");
txtFirstName.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "FIRSTNAME");
txtLastName.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "LASTNAME");
txtAddress.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "ADDRESS");
txtTelephone.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "TELEPHONE");
txtEmailAddress.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "EMAIL");
```

I also have a DataGridView below the Text Boxes, showing the contents of the DataTable.

```
dgvAuthor.DataSource = dt;
```

Now when I want to add a new row, i do

```
bm.AddNew();
```

where bm is defined in Form_Load as

```
BindingManagerBase bm;
bm = this.BindingContext[dt];
```

And when the save button is clicked after all the information is entered and validated, i do

```
this.BindingContext[dt].EndCurrentEdit();

try
{
da.Update(dt);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

However the problem comes where when I usually enter a row to the database (using SQL Plus) , I use a my_pk_sequence.nextval for the primary key. But how do i specify that when i add a new row in this method?

I catch this exception
`ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SYSMAN".AUTHOR.AUTHORID")` which is obvious because nothing was specified for the primary key. How do get around this? Thanx a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to create trigger that will automatically generate value on insert.
Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name 
   BEFORE INSERT ON SYSMAN.AUTHOR.AUTHORID 
   REFERENCING 
      OLD AS OLD 
      NEW AS NEW 
   FOR EACH ROW      
   BEGIN
       SELECT my_sequence.NEXTVAL
       INTO :NEW.AUTHORID
       FROM DUAL;
   END;
```

**Edit:**

Here is quote from Wikipedia on DUAL table:

> The DUAL table is a special one-row table present by default in all Oracle database installations.

Since `DUAL` table is important in ORACLE, here are some resources where you can learn about it:

- [DUAL table from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_table)
- [Ask Tom "All about the DUAL table"](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1562813956388)
- StackOverflow: [What is the dual table in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73751/what-is-the-dual-table-in-oracle)
- Google query: [Oracle Dual Table](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=oracle+dual+table)
- Oracle documantation articles:

  - [The Data Dictionary](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datadict.htm)
  - [Selecting from the DUAL Table](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries009.htm)

Comment: Awesome :) One question, what is Dual? :)