# Transform multiple queries into single row

Tags: sql, reporting

I have a report that I would like to base on a single SQL statement. The problem is the data is based on several SQL statements. For example.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as 'Cases Opened' 
FROM tblCases 
WHERE DateAssigned BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate

SELECT COUNT(*) as 'Cases Closed' 
FROM tblCases 
WHERE ClosedDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate

SELECT COUNT(*) as 'Tickets Issued' 
FROM tblTicket 
WHERE DateIssued BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate

SELECT COUNT(*) as 'Warnings Issued' 
FROM tblWarning 
WHERE DateIssued BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

Is there a way to turn these four seperate SQL statements into a single SQL statement such that each result is listed as a column? For example ..

```
Cases Opened        Cases Closed       Tickets Issued        Warnings Issued
******************************************************************************
   256         |      165          |        56           |          165
```

*EDIT* I am using SQL Server and no there is no relationship between the tables.

Comment: Is there a join-able relationship between the 3 tables?

Comment: Is t his oracle or sql server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select 
 (
 SELECT COUNT(*)  
 FROM tblCases 
 WHERE DateAssigned BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
 ) as 'Cases Opened' ,
 (SELECT COUNT(*)  
 FROM tblCases 
 WHERE ClosedDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
 ) as 'Cases Closed' ,
 (SELECT COUNT(*)  
 FROM tblTicket 
 WHERE DateIssued BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
 ) as 'Tickets Issued' ,
 (SELECT COUNT(*) 
 FROM tblWarning 
 WHERE DateIssued BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
 )  as 'Warnings Issued'
from dual
```

from dual would be necessary in oracle, mysql supports it but is not necessary and I'm not sure about sqlserver since I don't have one in front of me.

Comment: but "from dual" is not available in all SGBDs

Comment: It isn't necessary in SQL Server.

Comment: @Chuck Vose: Ofc this is "better" :) source http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73751/what-is-the-dual-table-in-oracle

Comment: Agreed. Must remember that SO has everything :P

Answer (score 1):

You could union and pivot the data, like so:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN FieldName='Cases Opened' THEN Value ELSE 0 END) AS Cases_Opened,
       SUM(CASE WHEN FieldName='Cases Closed' THEN Value ELSE 0 END AS Cases_Closed,
       SUM(CASE WHEN FieldName='Warning Issued' THEN Value ELSE 0 END) AS Warnings_Issued,
       SUM(CASE WHEN FieldName='Tickets Issued' THEN Value ELSE 0 END) AS Tickets_Issued
FROM 
(
SELECT COUNT(*) as Value, 'Cases Opened' as FieldName
FROM tblCases 
WHERE DateAssigned BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate

UNION

SELECT COUNT(*) as Value, 'Cases Closed' as FieldName
FROM tblCases 
WHERE ClosedDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate

UNION

SELECT COUNT(*) as Value, 'Tickets Issued' as FieldName
FROM tblTicket 
WHERE DateIssued BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate

UNION

SELECT COUNT(*) as Value, 'Warnings Issued' as FieldName
FROM tblWarning 
WHERE DateIssued BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the pivot statement if you are running in SQLServer