# PL/SQL Function Error - PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IS"

Tags: function, plsql, compiler-errors

I am trying to create a simple PL/SQL function but its returning error -> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IS". I am not sure whats wrong here, so could anybody out there please help. I followed the following steps -

`Step1` - Logged in as sysdba using - `sqlplus / as sysdba`

`Step2` - Created a file name `test.sql` with following code under `C:\` -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION employer_details_func
RETURN VARCHAR(20);
IS 
  emp_name VARCHAR(20); 
BEGIN 
SELECT first_name INTO emp_name
FROM emp_tbl WHERE empID = '100';
RETURN emp_name;
END;
/
```

`Step3` - Ran the following commands -

```
SQL>@C:\test.sql
Warning: Function created with compilation errors.
SQL> show error function Func;
Errors for FUNCTION FUNC:
LINE/COL ERROR
5/1      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IS"
SQL>
```

Don't know why am I getting this weird error. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: When you login AS SYSDBA you connect to the SYS account. Please please please do not do this.  SYS is a very powerful account because it owns the data dictionary.  Consequently it is very easy to corrupt the database working as SYS if we don't understand what we;re doing.  No offense, but the tenor of your question (a trivial syntax error) suggests this is your situation.  Use SYS to create an application user, then use that to create schema objects.

Answer (score 1):

Create your function as follows and try

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION employer_details_func
    RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    emp_name   VARCHAR2 (20);
BEGIN
    SELECT  first_name
      INTO  emp_name
      FROM  emp_tbl
     WHERE  empID = '100';

    RETURN emp_name;
END;
/
```

Comment: still the same error :( - 5/1      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IS"

Comment: Can you try executing your function from sql plus as `select employer_details_func from dual;`

Comment: Polppan - +1 for you :) - With the above statment, I am able to see the output - `SQL> select employer_details_func from dual;
EMPLOYER_DETAILS_FUNC
----------------------
sita`
All the functions are stored in dual? 
Not sure why the weird warning during compilation?

Comment: dual is kind of a dummy table where you can execute function using select statement. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73751/what-is-the-dual-table-in-oracle). When I executed your function from script, it compiled without any errors.

Comment: May be some software problem then. Anyways, you helped me a lot by suggesting to run it :). Thanks a bunch buddy. ++ for your suggestions.

Comment: @anujin And another point is I guess you creating this function as `sys` user under the same schema? Is not? If so any special reason for that? It is not a good practice to create your objects under `sys`. You should be doing that in other schemas, not in `SYS, SYSTEM` etc

Comment: With Oracle we should always use VARCHAR2 not VARCHAR.