# checking if a variable value is null on bash script

Tags: sql, unix, null, if-statement

i have this script that retrieves a parameter (a number) from a SQL query and assigns it to a variable.
there are two options - either the SQL query finds a value and then the script preforms 
echo "the billcycle number is $v_bc", or it doesnt find a value and it suppose to 
echo "no billcycle parameter found".
im having a problem with the if condition.

this is what i came up with:

```
#!/bin/bash


v_bc=`sqlplus -s /@bscsprod <<EOF
set pagesize 0
select billcycle from bc_run
where billcycle not in (50,16)
and control_group_ind is null
and billseqno=6043;
EOF`


if [ -z "$v_bc" ]; then echo no billcycle parameter found                     
else echo "the billcycle parameter is $v_bc"
fi
```

when billseqno=6043, then it means that v_bc=25, and when i run the script, the result is:
"the billcycle parameter is 25". which is what i ment it to do.
when i set billseqno=6042, according to the above SQL query, v_bc will get no value, therefore what i want it to do is echo "no billcycle parameter found".
instead i get

> "the billcycle parameter is
>
> > no rows were selected".

any suggestions ?

thanks very much
Assaf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try turning feedback off in sqlplus so that you don't get any output if no rows are selected:

```
v_bc=`sqlplus -s /@bscsprod <<EOF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
set pagesize 0
select billcycle from bc_run
where billcycle not in (50,16)
and control_group_ind is null
and billseqno=6043;
EOF`
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correctly checking for an empty value -- `v_bc` is just not empty, even with `-s`.

You may either:

- parse the output of `sqplus` when no rows are returned, so add this:

  `if [[ "$v_bc" == "no rows were selected" ]]; then v_bc=""; fi`

  This uses the bash `[[ ]]` command with "`==`" for pattern matching so we don't need to worry about leading/trailing whitespace. This is not as robust as dogbane's `SET FEEDBACK OFF` since it's entirely possible for "no rows were selected" to be valid data.
- write a better query which always returns data, like this: 
  http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:594023455752#followup-221571500346463844

  The trick being to reformulate your query and use select/union with a  fallback query that conditionally provides output when your query is empty:

```
with data as
  (select billcycle from bc_run where [...])
select * from data 
union all
select 'NA', null from dual where not exists (select null from data);
```

(see also [What is the dual table in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73751/what-is-the-dual-table-in-oracle) )

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
if [ "${v_bc:-SHOULDNTHAPPEN}" = "SHOULDNTHAPPEN" ]; then
  echo no billcycle parameter found
else......
```

Comment: Hello. thanks very much for your reply.the code you suggested does give the same result as if [ -z "$v_bc" ]; then echo no billcycle parameter found. 

would you mind explaining what it does ? didnt really get the SHOULDNTHAPPEN part (:

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic way to assign a value to a variable if that variable is empty is with an `=` in a parameter expansion.  In other words, this:

```
: ${v_bc:=no billcycle paramter found}
```

is equivalent to:

```
test -z "$v_bc" && v_bc='no billcycle paramter found'
```

In your case, it would also be easy to do:

```
echo ${v_bc:-no billcycle parameter found}
```

but the question asked in the title is not really the problem in your case.  (Since the problem is not that `v_bc` is the empty string, but rather that it is a value you do not expect.)