# Find id of all ads posted within the past three days, Sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to SQL. I have a table which contains information about ads. Which function should I use, to find id of all ads posted within the past three days?

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `SQL Server`? `MySQL`? `Oracle`? `DB2`? etc..

Comment: Also, post the table structure.

Comment: @JW, Oracle. it contains pdate which has date as domain, and some other information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Oracle DB, use this,

```
SELECT id
FROM tablename
WHERE TRUNC(pdate) >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 3;
```

**[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/189dc/1/0)**

Comment: Thanks, it works. Can you please explain, what does "DUAL" do here?

Comment: @MarshallBlack Info on [DUAL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73751/what-is-the-dual-table-in-oracle)

Comment: yeap, I was gonna do that, just was reading the article about dual

Answer (score 1):

```
Select ID --the id field
From tblAds --the ads table
WHERE Ad_Date >= DATEADD(day,-3,getDate()) --the filter. I am assuming Ad-Date is the name of the ad's date field
order by Ad_Date ASC -- order it
```

Comment: "date add- invalid identifier". I am getting this message

Comment: Google Oracle DateAdd function.