# What is an oracle dummy table?

Tags: oracle11g, dummy-data

I am now learning Oracle PL*SQL and having some understanding difficulties on dummy table which is called DUAL Table. Can someone explain what that is in a simple way? Please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the use of DUAL table in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310851/what-is-the-use-of-dual-table-in-oracle)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the dual table in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73751/what-is-the-dual-table-in-oracle)

Answer (score 3):

Clean and simple explanation @ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_table

> The DUAL table is a special one-row, one-column table present by default in Oracle and other database installations. In Oracle, the table has a single VARCHAR2(1) column called DUMMY that has a value of 'X'. It is suitable for use in selecting a pseudo column such as SYSDATE or USER.