# Select records count from multiple tables in a single query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have some models (restaurants, shops, products), and i want to select records count for multiple models in a single linq query.

I know how it should be in sql, but i don't know how to translate it in linq:

```
select
    (select count(*) from restaurants) as restaurantsCount,
    (select count(*) from shops) as shopsCount,
    (select count(*) from products) as productsCount
from
    dual
```

Comment: You can use LinQ `Union` statement to union sub query into

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Considering [`dual`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73751/what-is-the-dual-table-in-oracle) is a *dummy* table with single row:

```
var result = new 
{ 
    RestaurantsCount = context.Restaurants.Count(),
    ShopsCount = context.Shops.Count(),
    ProductsCount = context.Products.Count()
};
```

*Single query* solution:

```
        var result = from dummyRow in new List<string> { "X" }
                     join product in context.products on 1 equals 1 into pg
                     join shop in context.shops on 1 equals 1 into sg
                     join restaurant in context.restaurants on 1 equals 1 into rg
                     select new
                     {
                         productsCount = pg.Count(),
                         shopsCount = sg.Count(),
                         restaurantsCount = rg.Count()
                     };
```

Comment: In your case, will be executed three queires, instead one. Each for every Count().

Comment: @Alexander You do have same in your `SQL`. If the only problem is to have *single query* which actually doesn't change the way data will be fetched - I'll update the answer.

Comment: @AnatoliiGabuza is there no performance improvement by doing it in a single query?

Comment: In my case - the second solution (single query) was much slower - first it loaded all data and then count it.. instead of asking DB to just give counts (easy action) in separate queries