# SELECT without a TABLE (JDBC)

Tags: sql, jdbc, openedge

In most sql databases I have seen you can do something like:

```
SELECT ABS(-2.4)
```

and I get back 2.4. Notice there is no FROM clause.

When I try to do this in OpenEdge via Squirrel and the JDBC driver I get a syntax error. Is there a way to run SELECT statements like this (sans FROM clause) via JDBC?

Comment: I think that is platform-dependant.  For example, oracle as the "DUAL" dummy table to use for that.  Don't know about other systems.

Comment: I'm wanting to know about OpenEdge specifically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Single row/column Dual equivalent; [`SYSPROGRESS.SYSCALCTABLE`](http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge113/oe113html/Data%20Management/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#href=SQL%20Reference/10dmsrfSysCat.142.06.html&single=true)

Comment: Can you explain your answer a bit more please? I think what you are saying is to add this to the FROM clause, which I know works. Is there a way to NOT include the FROM? If not is there a particular reason as to why you must include this table? I notice you cannot even do something like SELECT 2 + 2.

Comment: Its simply because the semantics of the engine's SQL dialect require that a FROM clause be specified with a SELECT, so that's what you must do. Related for Oracle; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73751/what-is-the-dual-table-in-oracle

Comment: I haven't worked much with Oracle so interesting to know. Incidentally, I notice if I SELECT 2+2 FROM AnotherTable (existing table) it will output for each existing row.

Comment: Aye, that behaviour will be constant across all databases

Comment: I didn't know if it differed until I tried it. I didn't even consider that some databases required a table. To me it seems a bit inflexible.