# oracle take mean value of one column across different dates

Tags: sql, oracle, mean, date-range

There is one column called `Price`, and another column called `Date_1`, which include data from now to about one year later. 
I want to find the mean value of `Price` across different dates. Ex, 2 weeks from now, 1 month from now, 6 months from now...

Can I use `Case When` function to do it?

Given:

```
Location_id |     Date_1  | Price 
------------+-------------+------
   L_1      | 20-JUL-2016 |  105 
   L_1      | 21-JUL-2016 |  117
   ...      |    ...      |  ... 
   L_1      | 16-MAY-2017 |  103 
   L_2      | 20-JUL-2016 |   99 
   L_2      | 21-JUL-2016 |  106 
   ...      |    ...      |  ... 
   L_2      | 16-MAY-2017 |  120
```

To get:

```
Location_id |  Period  | Average_Price 
------------+----------+--------------
   L_1      | 2  weeks |   ... 
   L_1      | 6 months |   ... 
   L_1      | 1 year   |   ... 
   L_2      | 2 weeks  |   ... 
   L_2      | 6 months |   ...
   L_2      | 1 year   |   ...
```

Where in "Period", '2 weeks' means 2 weeks from start date (sysdate). And "Average_Price" is the mean value of price across that period.

Thanks! This problem solved. And I cam across an additional one:

There is another table that contains date information :

```
Location_id |  Ex_start_date  | Ex_end_date 
------------+-----------------+--------------
   L_1      | 08-JUN-16       |   30-AUG-16
   L_1      | 21-SEP-16       |   25-SEP-16
   L_1      | 08-MAY-17       |   12-MAY-17
   L_2      | 08-AUG-16       |   21-AUG-16
   L_2      | 24-OCT-16       |   29-OCT-16
   L_2      | 15-MAR-17       |   19-MAR-17
```

Beyond "Ex_Start_date" and "Ex_End_date" is 'Non_Ex' period. After I obtain average information of 2 weeks and 6 months period, I would like to I would like to add one more column, to obtain mean price for 'Non_Ex' and 'Ex' conditions as above.

Hopefully, a table as below can be obtained:

```
Location_id |  Period        | Ex_Condition    |   Average_Price 
------------+----------------+----------------------------------
   L_1      | 2 weeks        |   Ex period     |   ...
   L_1      | 2 weeks        |   Non-Ex period |   ...
   L_1      | 6 months       |   Ex period     |   ...
   L_1      | 6 months       |   Non-Ex period |   ...                                                 
   L_2      | 2 weeks        |   Ex period     |   ...
   L_2      | 2 weeks        |   Non-Ex period |   ...
   L_2      | 6 months       |   Ex period     |   ...
   L_2      | 6 months       |   Non-Ex period |   ...
```

The average price will return 'null' if there is no dates falling in EX Period or Non-Ex Period.

And how can I make it happen? Thanks!

Comment: Sample data and desired results.

Comment: provide more information please.

Comment: data like:   Location_id     Date           Price      
                   L_1      20-JUL-2016    105
                     ...             ...         ...
                   L_1       16-MAY-2017    103
                   L_2       20-JUL-2016     99
         ...             ...         ...
                   L_2      16-MAY-2017    120                                                  to get  Location_id        Period       Average_Price
      L_1         2 weeks        ...
      L_1         6 months       ...
      L_2         2 weeks        ...
      L_2         6 months       ...

Comment: @Crubal Chenxi Li Please edit your original post with this information.

Comment: @CrubalChenxiLi It's still not clear what *exact* results you want to get. Please [edit] your question and add the expected Average_Price and the missing rows in your input data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
select   location_id,
         period,
         sum(in_period * price) / nullif(sum(in_period), 0) as avg_price
from     (select location_id,
                 price,
                 period,
                 case when mydate - days < sysdate then 1 else 0 end in_period
          from   localprice,
                 ( select '2 weeks' as period, 14 as days from dual
                   union 
                   select '6 months', 183 from dual
                 ) intervals
         ) detail
group by location_id, 
         period
```

Replace *localprice* with the name of your table (you did not provide its name in your question).

Replace *mydate* with the actual name of your date column. I don't expect you called it *date*, as that is a reserved word and would require you to always quote it -- don't do that: choose another name.

`dual` is a standard object available in Oracle, which can be used to introduce rows in a query - rows which you don't have in a table somewhere.

Alternatively, you could create a table with all periods that interest you (2 weeks, 4 weeks, ..., together with the number of days they represent) and use that instead of the union select on dual.

Here is an [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ae8b0/2). Note that it runs on Postgres, because the Oracle instance is not available at this moment. For that reason I created `dual` explicitly and used `current_date` instead of `sysdate`. But for the rest it is the same.

Comment: Thanks! May I ask what is "dual" and "localprice"?

Comment: This may help explain  dual: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73751/what-is-the-dual-table-in-oracle

Comment: *localprce* is just your table (you did not provide its name in your question). *dual* is a standard object that exists in Oracle, which can be used to introduce rows in a query. Alternatively, you could create a table with all periods that interest you (2 weeks, 4 weeks, ...) and use that instead of the `union` select on *dual*.

Comment: Thanks! I just tried, it seems that mean value of "6 months" is the same as that of "2 weeks". I guess is only the first observation returned?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. The value *could* of course be the same for a certain data set, but in general it is not (I tested this). Make sure you have data that has dates further in the future than 2 weeks.

Comment: Yes, I made that mistake as you mentioned. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I had just added some "proof" by creating a fiddle :)

Answer (score 0):

NOT TESTED because OP didn't provide input data in usable format.

You probably want something along the lines of

```
select   location_id, '2 weeks' as period, avg(price) as average_price
from     base_table
where    price is not null
         and
         "date" between SYSDATE and SYSDATE + 13  
                                -- or however you want to define the two week interval
group by location_id
union all
select   location_id, '6 months' as period, avg(price) as average_price
from     base_table
where    price is not null
         and
         "date" between SYSDATE and add_months(SYSDATE, 6) - 1  
                                -- or however you want to define the six month interval
group by location_id
;
```

Note that `date` is a reserved Oracle keyword which should not be used as a column name; if you do, you'll have to use double-quotes, match case (upper and lower) exactly, and you may still run into various problems later. Better to only use table and column names that are not reserved words.

Comment: Thanks! I would avoid that. By the way, for 'base_table', I have to refer every that I use "select and union all" function, right?

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question. Do you mean, do you have to refer to "base_table" (instead, use your actual table or view name here!) twice, because there is a UNION ALL? Then the answer is yes; when you use UNION ALL, both parts of the UNION are full "SELECT statements" with a FROM clause where you must reference the base table.

Answer (score 0):

This is a re-phrased version of the @trincot answer. It should be faster over a bigger dataset.

- Rows which are unwanted are skipped, not zeroed and used. You won't get a result row any more if there no localprice which match the intervals criteria.
- It still only scans localprice once unlike the @mathguy answer.
- If the real local price has a highly selective index on date then it can be used.
- Un-commenting the line in the `WHERE` clause will help discard lines early i.e. before the intervals table is considered. The `ORDERED` hint may well be unnecessary in real life but it demonstrates the correct explain plan when using this line with this data.
- Use `UNION ALL` rather that `UNION` when gluing rows which are going to be unique.

As usual, don't believe any answer until you've proved it in your circumstances.

`WITH
  localprice AS
    ( SELECT 'L_1' Location_id, TO_DATE('20-JUN-2016') "DATE", 105 Price FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'L_1' Location_id, TO_DATE('16-MAY-2017') "DATE", 103 Price FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'L_2' Location_id, TO_DATE('20-JUN-2016') "DATE",  99 Price FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'L_2' Location_id, TO_DATE('16-MAY-2017') "DATE", 120 Price FROM DUAL
    ),
  intervals AS
    ( SELECT '2 weeks' AS period, 14 AS days FROM dual
      UNION ALL
      SELECT '6 months', 183 FROM dual
    )
SELECT /*+ ORDERED */
  location_id, period,
  AVG(price) AS avg_price
FROM
  localprice
    CROSS JOIN
  intervals
WHERE "DATE" >= SYSDATE - days
--  AND "DATE" >= SYSDATE - (SELECT MAX(days) FROM intervals)
GROUP BY location_id, period`