# Cursor for loop in procedure with called function in Oracle

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

The table is:

```
F TIME1                                                                       END_TIME                          
- --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------
C 16-NOV-16 09.45.32.000000 AM                                                17-NOV-16 09.45.32.000000 AM      
A 16-NOV-16 10.14.54.000000 AM                                                16-NOV-16 11.14.54.000000 AM      
A 16-NOV-16 10.14.56.000000 AM                                                16-NOV-16 11.14.56.000000 AM
```

I have created a function..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION datediff
(
time1 TIMESTAMP
, time2 TIMESTAMP
)
RETURN number
as
tot number;
BEGIN
SELECT(extract(DAY FROM time2-time1)*24*60*60)+
(extract(HOUR FROM time2-time1)*60*60)
 into tot from tt ;

RETURN tot;
END;
```

I am then calling the function in procedure...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P1
IS 
  CURSOR c1
   IS    
   select count(*) as cnt,time1,end_time
   from tt group by time1,end_time ;

  a number;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN c1
  LOOP
    declare
      a number;
    BEGIN
      insert into y1 values(i.cnt,datediff(i.time1,i.end_time)) ;

      --display(i.cnt||'        '||a);

    /* EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('Error updating record ' || SUBSTR (SQLERRM, 1, 250));*/
    END;

  END LOOP;

END P1;
```

The error I am getting is ...

```
SQL> exec p1
BEGIN p1; END;
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "ANU.DATEDIFF", line 11
ORA-06512: at "ANU.P1", line 14
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

This is working for single record in the table ,but not for multiple records..?  please guide..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `datediff` function.

Whenever you have a `SELECT ... INTO ...` statement in PL/SQL, the `SELECT` query must return a single row.  If it returns no rows at all, you get an `ORA-01403 no data found` error, and if it returns more than one row, you get the `ORA-01422 exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows` error you see above.

So, how can you get your query to return one row?  Well, you can start by noticing that you aren't selecting any values from of the table `tt`.  All your query is returning is the same value for each row in `tt`.  If `tt` has one row, your query returns the value once.  If `tt` has three rows, your query returns the same value three times.  All this is unnecessary as you only want the one value, regardless of how many rows there are in `tt`.

So instead of `SELECT`ing from `tt`, use the [built-in table `dual`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73751/what-is-the-dual-table-in-oracle) instead.  The `dual` table only ever has one row in it:

```
SELECT(extract(DAY FROM time2-time1)*24*60*60)+
(extract(HOUR FROM time2-time1)*60*60)
 into tot from dual;
```

However, in your case you don't even need a query: your `datediff` function could be rewritten to just perform the calculation and return the value:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION datediff
(
time1 TIMESTAMP
, time2 TIMESTAMP
)
RETURN number
as
BEGIN
 RETURN (extract(DAY FROM time2-time1)*24*60*60)+
        (extract(HOUR FROM time2-time1)*60*60);
END;
/
```

Comment: Wonderful.. thank you so much for the detailed explanation.can i get your email id pls

Comment: @swathi: no, sorry, you can't have my email address. I don't give that out on Stack Overflow.

Comment: no prob Luke, i tried to implement as u suggested... as follows,

Comment: the function...     CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION datediff
 (
 time1 TIMESTAMP
 , time2 TIMESTAMP,
t2 out number
 )
 -- RETURN NUMBER
 RETURN number
 as
 t1 number;
  BEGIN
 SELECT (extract(DAY FROM time2-time1)*24),
 (extract(HOUR FROM time2-time1))
  into t1,t2 from dual;
 RETURN t1;
 END;

Comment: ------------- the procedure is.....--------------      CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P1
       IS
       CURSOR c1
        IS
        select count(*) as cnt,time1,end_time
        from tt group by time1,end_time ;
        a number;
   mi number;
        BEGIN
 execute immediate 'truncate table y1';
        FOR i IN c1
       LOOP
        declare
   a number;
        b varchar2(23);
        BEGIN
   a:= datediff(i.time1,i.end_time,mi);
   b:=a||':'||mi;
   insert into y1 values(i.cnt,b);

Comment: /* EXCEPTION
                WHEN OTHERS THEN
                    dbms_output.put_line('Error updating record ' || SUBSTR (SQLERRM, 1, 250));*/
            END;
       END LOOP;
       END P1;
 -------------              exec p1; ----------   select * from y1;

   CNT TIME
------ ----------------------
     1 24:0
     1 0:1
     1 0:1

Comment: -------------------it working   ... but me requirement is ... select * from y1;

   CNT TIME
------ ----------------------
     1 24:0
     2 0:1
       there cnt should be grouped , when time is same.... am trying but facing multiple errors in procedure...  can u guide me ...plz?

Comment: i modifies as.... 
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION datediff
   (
 diff timestamp,
 --time2 TIMESTAMP,
 --time1 TIMESTAMP,
  t2 out number
   )
   -- RETURN NUMBER
   RETURN number
   as
   t1 number;
    BEGIN
   SELECT (extract(DAY FROM diff)*24),
   (extract(HOUR FROM diff))
    into t1,t2 from dual;
   RETURN t1;
   END;

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P1
        IS
        CURSOR c1
         IS
         select count(*) as cnt, (end_time-time1) as diff
         from tt group by (end_time-time1);
         a number;
    mi number;
         BEGIN
  execute immediate 'truncate table y1';
         FOR i IN c1

Comment: LOOP
         declare
    a number;
         b varchar2(23);
         BEGIN
    a:= datediff(i.diff,mi);
    b:=a||':'||mi;
    insert into y1 values(i.cnt,b);
      /* EXCEPTION
                 WHEN OTHERS THEN
                     dbms_output.put_line('Error updating record ' || SUBSTR (SQLERRM, 1, 250))*/
             END;
        END LOOP;
        END P1;

Comment: the error is............
Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err
Errors for PROCEDURE P1:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- ----------------------------------------------------------------
17/4     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
17/8     PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
         'DATEDIFF'

Comment: also the following error.....SQL> exec p1;
BEGIN p1; END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month
ORA-06512: at "ANU.DATEDIFF", line 13
ORA-06512: at "ANU.P1", line 17
ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: @swathi: *never*, **ever**, ***EVER*** post that much code in comments.  If you've updated your code and changed things and it isn't working, ask a new question instead.