# Whats the Oracle equivalent of SELECT 'TEST' as MyColumn

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

In MSSQL I can type into script editor and execute the following:

```
SELECT 'TEST' AS MyColumn
```

Which will output a single row containing TEST in a column called MyColumn

[image]

What is the equivalent in Oracle?

Comment: I agree the question is the same as the one linked but if I have no idea about the dual table as a new user to Oracle, Litterally been using it for half a day how would I know that the following question is the same? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73751/what-is-the-dual-table-in-oracle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need `FROM DUAL`:

```
SELECT 'TEST' AS MyColumn
FROM DUAL;
```

`DUAL` is a special built-in table that has one row.

Answer (score 6):

it is:

```
SELECT 'TEST' AS MyColumn FROM dual;
```

Dual is a table with one column and one record, built into Oracle especially for this purpose:

```
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

yields

```
Dummy
-----
X
```

If you would construct this table in other databases, queries on dual would also work. (I use this to unit test Oralcle-queries on Sqlite)

Answer (score 2):

add 'from dual' at the end so

```
select 'Test' AS MyColumn from dual;
```