# Is there any alternative to use MYSQL's ADDDATE() in ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have this query that needs to be executed for oracle sql instead of mysql which is where it originally came from, but I have the **ADDDATE()** function which I don't see any other alternative than **DateAdd** since it needs more parameters than I really need..

Apart from that, if I try to execute it, it also indicates an error in the

> SELECT 0 i UNION.................

part, saying the following **ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected**
Maybe in oracle it is not allowed to do a select 0 union select 1 union...
Any suggestions or help I appreciate it, thanks

```
SELECT 
                    ADDDATE('1970-01-01', t4.i * 10000 + t3.i * 1000 + t2.i * 100 + t1.i * 10 + t0.i) selected_date
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
                    ) t0,
                    (
                        SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
                    ) t1,
                    (
                        SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
                    ) t2,
                    (
                    SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
                    ) t3,
                    (
                    SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
                    ) t4
```

Comment: You need to SELECT FROM something. DUAL perhaps?

Comment: @jarlh Oh right, I hadn't realized that making a dual selection would work... I'll give it a try thanks!

Comment: Please check [Datetime arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-E405BBC7-DA9A-4DF2-9F22-E60CB9EC0705) section. You may use `date_variable + n`, where `n` is a number of days or explicit `date_var + interval 'n' days`

Comment: Are you just trying to add a number of days to a DATE or TIMESTAMP?

Comment: @Pugzly for date

Comment: On a side note: `UNION [DISTINCT]` is inappropriate here. Don't tell the DBMS to look for duplicates to remove, when there can't be any. 0 will never equal 1 or 2 or ... Use `UNION ALL` instead. But well, since MySQL 8 you can write a recursive query instead, anyway. Please see my answer. The query is standard SQL, only that it must be `with dates` in Oracle, but `with recursive dates` in MySQL.

Comment: @Wail it's not *making a dual selection*, it's that in current versions of Oracle, `select` syntax requires a corresponding `from` clause (in accordance with ANSI standards I believe). This may be relaxed in version 23c, but at the time of writing this is not yet released. This is why you can't just `select 0;` and also why Oracle provide a dummy table for cases where there is no real source table. Nobody knows why it's called `dual`, it's just an accident of history. (Actually there is a [story about it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73816/230471) but tbh it's never really made sense to me.)

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle you must select from the one-row table dual in order to select one row. You cannot select without a from clause.

If you want to generate dates, you'll write a standard SQL recursive CTE. (And this is the typical approach now in MySQL, too, since version 8.0.)

Here is an example selecting all days for 1970:

```
with dates (dt) as
(
  select date '1970-01-01' from dual
  union all
  select dt + interval '1' day from dates where dt < date '1970-12-31'
)
select dt from dates;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to SELECT a list of dates for the year 1970. Adjust the starting and ending dates if you want different years or the INTERVAL if you want different periods like seconds, minutes, hours…

```
 ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';


with dt (dt, interv) as (
select date '1970-01-01', numtodsinterval(1,'DAY') from dual
union all
select dt.dt + interv, interv from dt
where dt.dt + interv <= date '1970-12-31')
select dt from dt;
/
```