# Query in postgresql similar to insert all in oracle

Tags: postgresql

There is an "insert all" request in Oracle.

```
INSERT ALL

  INTO mytable1 (empId, name, last_name) VALUES (expr1, expr2, expr_n)

  INTO mytable2 (empId, address) VALUES (o_expr1, o_expr2, o_expr_n)


SELECT * FROM dual;
```

How can I similarly insert records into postgres in a single request? I don't have any return values.

Comment: Why do you need it to be a single request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use a [common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

```
WITH _a AS (
  INSERT INTO mytable1 (empId, name, last_name)
  VALUES (expr1, expr2, expr_n)
), _b AS (
  INSERT INTO mytable2 (empId, address)
  VALUES (o_expr1, o_expr2, o_expr_n)
)
SELECT 'X' AS dummy;
```

(The final `SELECT` attempts to mirror [the Oracle idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19224594/1048572) but you can omit it)

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason, in this case, even in Oracle to use `Insert All`. The `values` are defined variables in a procedural block (pl/sql), they are not derived from the select following. So there is no reason you need a single statement in Postgres. 2 Inserts within a procedural block (plpgsql) will accomplish exactly the same. So

```
declare ... 
begin
    ...
    insert into mytable1 (empid, name, last_name)
         values (expr1, expr2, expr_n);

    insert into mytable2 (empid, address) 
         values (o_expr1, o_expr2, o_expr_n);
    ...
end;
```

Would do exactly the same. And IMHO easier to understand than DML within a CTE.

**NOTE:**

As written these will not run in Oracle nor in Posrgres. The insert for `mytable2` names 2 columns to be inserted, but contains 3 values. Those **must** match. I am guessing this is a copy/paste error.

Comment: Yes, this is a mistake. Unfortunately, I will be executing the query from the application, so I can't use procedural blocks