# Oracle Retrieve a Column of hard-coded values in a Select Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I am trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT 'John Doe' example_name;

Result:

example_name
John Doe
```

I can do this in `PostgreSQL` and `SQL Server`, but this does not work in Oracle.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hint: `FROM DUAL`

Comment: Yes, DUAL is typically what we use. However, it can actually be *any* table if you add ROWNUM = 1. The point is to generate a single row and supply the only column as a literal. DUAL is a table with one row. But we could all do the same things if it didn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Prior to version 23c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqlrf/Selecting-from-the-DUAL-Table.html), Oracle requires you to use [the `DUAL` table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73751/what-is-the-dual-table-in-oracle) when synthesising table data from values:

[This works for me in Oracle 11g R2 on SQLFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/42000/1):

```sql
SELECT
    'John Doe' AS example_name
FROM
    dual;
```

Screenshot proof:

[image]

Comment: Just tried it out after your Hint, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Will mark this as the answer in 11 minutes when SO let's me.